# How to check if a string contains a substring in Bash

Tags: string, bash, shell, substring, sh

I have a string in Bash:

```sh
string="My string"
```

How can I test if it contains another string?

```sh
if [ $string ?? 'foo' ]; then
  echo "It's there!"
fi
```

Where `??` is my unknown operator. Do I use `echo` and `grep`?

```sh
if echo "$string" | grep 'foo'; then
  echo "It's there!"
fi
```

That looks a bit clumsy.

Comment: Hi, if empty strings are false, why do you consider it clumsy? It was the only way that worked for me, despite the proposed solutions.

Comment: Here's one for posix shells: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829613/how-do-you-tell-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-unix-shell-scripting

Comment: Please use *$needle in a $haystack* idiom in your example. It's much easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 4849, accepted):

You can use [Marcus's answer (* wildcards)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/229585/3755692) outside a case statement, too, if you use double brackets:

```
string='My long string'
if [[ $string == *"My long"* ]]; then
  echo "It's there!"
fi
```

Note that spaces in the needle string need to be placed between double quotes, and the `*` wildcards should be outside. Also note that a simple comparison operator is used (i.e. `==`), not the regex operator `=~`.

Comment: Also note that you can reverse the comparison by just switching to != in the test. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Hmm, with this exact code, I get `[[: not found`. Any idea what's wrong? I'm using GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1), on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Jonik: You may be missing the shebang or have it as `#!/bin/sh`. Try `#!/bin/bash` instead.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Avoid using either. For portability, you should use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` instead of `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that it won't work with the single `[` operator (the double brackets `[[` are probably mandatory with wildcards)

Comment: Yep, this solution is not POSIX. Will not work with `sh` in many docker containers.

Comment: The question was explicitly for Bash.  POSIX compliance is a red herring.

Answer (score 999):

If you prefer the regex approach:

```
string='My string';

if [[ $string =~ "My" ]]; then
   echo "It's there!"
fi
```

Comment: Had to replace an egrep regex in a bash script, this worked perfectly!

Comment: The `=~` operator already searches the whole string for a match; the `.*`'s here are extraneous. Also, quotes are generally preferable to backslashes: `[[ $string =~ "My s" ]]`

Comment: @bukzor Quotes stopped working here as of Bash 3.2+: http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ `E14)`.  It's probably best to assign to a variable (using quotes), then compare.  Like this: `re="My s"; if [[ $string =~ $re ]]`

Comment: Test if it does **NOT** contain a string:  `if [[ ! "abc" =~ "d" ]]` is true.

Answer (score 488):

I am not sure about using an if statement, but you can get a similar effect with a case statement:

```
case "$string" in 
  *foo*)
    # Do stuff
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution since it is portable to posix shells. (a.k.a. no bashisms)

Comment: @technosaurus I find it rather odd to criticize "bashism" in a question  that has only bash tag :)

Comment: @P.P. It's not so much a criticism as the preference of a more universal solution over a more limited one. Please consider that, years later, people (like me) will stop by to look for this answer and may be pleased to find one that's useful in a wider scope than the original question. As they say in the Open Source world: "choice is good!"

Comment: @technosaurus, FWIW `[[ $string == *foo* ]]` also works in some POSIX compliant sh versions (e.g. `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` on Solaris 10) and ksh (>= 88)

Comment: @maxschlepzig nowadays many people work with docker containers. Most default docker images do not have bash and something like `[[ $string == *foo* ]]` will not work.

Answer (score 351):

**Full rewrite 2023-07-03!!**

## String contain: POSIX compatibility, `bash` case independent, hints and remarks.

### Introduction

Previous answer was based on *parameter expansion*, but after doing comparison with *case* based solution, as proposed by [Marcus Griep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/229585/1765658), I have to confess: *case* method is a **lot** more efficient!

### Brief essential

```bash
case $string in
    *$substring* )
         do something with "$substring"
         ;;
esac
```

As a function:

```bash
stringContain() { case $2 in *$1* ) return 0;; *) return 1;; esac ;}
```

#### Usage sample

```bash
for string in 'echo "My string"'    "Don't miss quotes"    ''; do # 3 strings
    for substr in "'t mis"   'o "My'   "s"   "Y"   ""; do # 5 substrings
        if stringContain "$substr" "$string"; then
            printf 'Match: %-12s %s\n' "'$substr'" "'$string'"
        else
            printf 'No match: %s\n' "'$substr'"
        fi
    done
done
```

```
No match: ''t mis'
Match: 'o "My'      'echo "My string"'
Match: 's'          'echo "My string"'
No match: 'Y'
Match: ''           'echo "My string"'
Match: ''t mis'     'Don't miss quotes'
No match: 'o "My'
Match: 's'          'Don't miss quotes'
No match: 'Y'
Match: ''           'Don't miss quotes'
No match: ''t mis'
No match: 'o "My'
No match: 's'
No match: 'Y'
Match: ''           ''
```

### Alternative using *parameter expansion*

In previous answer I'd proposed:

```bash
stringContain() { [ -z "$1" ] || { [ -z "${2##*$1*}" ] && [ -n "$2" ];};}
```

But after doing some comparisons, using `dash`, `busybox shell`, `bash` and `ksh`, here is *my* average result:

```
Comparing time PExp vs Case method under bash    :    634.71%
Comparing time PExp vs Case method under dash    :    878.87%
Comparing time PExp vs Case method under ksh     :    217.95%
Comparing time PExp vs Case method under busybox :    752.42%
```

Full test script: [stringContain-test.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/stringContain-test.sh.txt)

> *`case` method is at least 2 time quicker than `parameter expansion` method regardless *shell* implementation used.*

#### Semantically:

- case method: in case *string* match anything (could be nothing), followed by *substring*, followed by anything. is a single test.
- *parameter expansion*: If *substring* is empty or *string* where anything followed by *substring* followed by anything is replaced by nothing is nothing and string do contain something is a complex multiple test after string transformation

From this point of view, this seem easy to understand that *`case` method* is more efficient!

### Case independent

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and some other [shell](/questions/tagged/shell), you could use *parameter expansion* to quickly transform your string to *lower* or *upper* case, by using respectively: `${var,,}` and `${var^^}`:

So adding `-i` option to function, for *case independent*, could be done by:

```bash
stringContain() {
    if [[ $1 == -i ]] ; then
        case ${3,,} in
            *${2,,}*) return 0;;
            *) return 1;;
        esac
    else
        case $2 in
            *$1*) return 0;;
            *) return 1;;
        esac
    fi
}
```

```bash
stringContain hello 'Hello world!' && echo yes || echo no
no
stringContain -i hello 'Hello world!' && echo yes || echo no
yes
```

Comment: This would be even better, if you can figure out some way to put that to a function.

Comment: @EeroAaltonen How do you find my (new added) function?

Comment: I know! find . -name "*" | xargs grep "myfunc" 2> /dev/null

Comment: @eggmatters Question stand for *string* that contain *string* (not file containing string).

Comment: @F.Hauri Sorry, was a joke to your comment to EuroAaltonen The find command has absolutely nothing to do with the question posted on this thread.

Comment: $F.Hauri It is what I was thinking and hoping for. The only change I would make is to the name. I propose "stringContain", since at least integers are supported.

Comment: This is wonderful because it's so compatible. One bug, though: It does not work if the haystack string is empty. The correct version would be `string_contains() { [ -z "${2##*$1*}" ] && [ -n "$2" -o -z "$1" ]; }`

A final thought: does the empty string contain the empty string? The version above things yes (because of the `-o -z "$1"` part).

Comment: **Special case:** The string to search for is **the first** word in each lines (*`processor`* in *`/proc/cpuinfo`*) see [this answer to *How to obtain the number of CPUs/cores in Linux from the command line?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48749737/1765658)!

Answer (score 188):

You should remember that shell scripting is less of a language and more of a collection of commands. Instinctively you think that this "language" requires you to follow an `if` with a `[` or a `[[`. Both of those are just commands that return an exit status indicating success or failure (just like every other command). For that reason I'd use `grep`, and not the `[` command.

Just do:

```bash
if grep -q foo <<<"$string"; then
    echo "It's there"
fi
```

Now that you are thinking of `if` as testing the exit status of the command that follows it (complete with semi-colon), why not reconsider the source of the string you are testing?

```bash
## Instead of this
filetype="$(file -b "$1")"
if grep -q "tar archive" <<<"$filetype"; then
#...

## Simply do this
if file -b "$1" | grep -q "tar archive"; then
#...
```

The `-q` option makes grep not output anything, as we only want the return code. `<<<` makes the shell expand the next word and use it as the input to the command, a one-line version of the `<<` here document (I'm not sure whether this is standard or a Bashism).

Comment: they are called [here strings (3.6.7)](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html) I believe it is bashism

Comment: one can also use [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) `if grep -q foo <(echo somefoothing); then`

Comment: Note that `echo` is unportable, if you're passing a variable, use `printf '%s' "$string` instead.

Comment: @nyuszika7h `echo` alone is pretty portable. The flags are not. If you find yourself thinking about `-e` or `-n` use `printf`

Comment: The cost of this is very expensive: doing `grep -q foo <<<"$mystring"` implie 1 fork and is *bashism* and `echo $mystring | grep -q foo` implie 2 forks (one for the pipe and the second for running `/path/to/grep`)

Comment: @BrunoBronosky `echo` without flags might still have unexpected portability problems if the argument string contains backslash sequences. `echo "nope\c"` is expected on some platforms to work like `echo -e "nope"` on some others. `printf '%s' "nope"` vs `printf '%s\n' 'nope\c'`

Answer (score 107):

The accepted answer is best, but since there's more than one way to do it, here's another solution:

```
if [ "$string" != "${string/foo/}" ]; then
    echo "It's there!"
fi
```

`${var/search/replace}` is `$var` with the first instance of `search` replaced by `replace`, if it is found (it doesn't change `$var`).  If you try to replace `foo` by nothing, and the string has changed, then obviously `foo` was found.

Comment: ephemient's solution above: > ` if [ "$string" != "${string/foo/}" ]; then echo "It's there!" fi` is useful when using BusyBox's shell *ash*. The accepted solution does not work with BusyBox because some bash's regular expressions are not implemented.

Comment: the inequality of difference. Pretty weird thought! I love it

Comment: unless your string is 'foo' though

Comment: I wrote this same solution myself (because my interpreter wouldn't take the top answers) then went looking for a better one, but found this!

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me: running Ubuntu Mate 20.04, `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` contains `MATE`, and running: ```if [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" != "${string/GNOME/}" ]; then 
echo MATCHES GNOME
fi
```  prints MATCHES GNOME... it thinks "MATE" matches "GNOME" ... dafuq?

Comment: @hanshenrik You're comparing `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` to `$string`. The expression you want is `if [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" != "${XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP/GNOME/}" ]; then  echo MATCHES GNOME; fi`

Comment: @venimus yeah, `"x$string" != "x${string/foo/}"` is better.

Comment: @TPoschel The accepted solution does not work in `ash` because `[[` is a `bash` addition; POSIX only defines `[` for shells and `ash` is basically a POSIX shell, so it only implements what POSIX does require from shells. But the `case` solution would work as well because case pattern matching is also defined by POSIX for shells.

Comment: if `repace` is empty, `${var/search/replace}` can be simplified to `${var/search}`

Answer (score 82):

So there are lots of useful solutions to the question - but which is fastest / uses the fewest resources?

Repeated tests using this frame:

```
/usr/bin/time bash -c 'a=two;b=onetwothree; x=100000; while [ $x -gt 0 ]; do TEST ; x=$(($x-1)); done'
```

Replacing TEST each time:

```
[[ $b =~ $a ]]           2.92 user 0.06 system 0:02.99 elapsed 99% CPU

[ "${b/$a//}" = "$b" ]   3.16 user 0.07 system 0:03.25 elapsed 99% CPU

[[ $b == *$a* ]]         1.85 user 0.04 system 0:01.90 elapsed 99% CPU

case $b in *$a):;;esac   1.80 user 0.02 system 0:01.83 elapsed 99% CPU

doContain $a $b          4.27 user 0.11 system 0:04.41 elapsed 99%CPU
```

(doContain was in F. Houri's answer)

And for giggles:

```
echo $b|grep -q $a       12.68 user 30.86 system 3:42.40 elapsed 19% CPU !ouch!
```

So the simple substitution option predictably wins whether in an extended test or a case. The case is portable.

Piping out to 100000 greps is predictably painful! The old rule about using external utilities without need holds true.

Comment: Neat benchmark. Convinced me to use `[[ $b == *$a* ]]`.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, `case` wins with the smallest overall time consumption.  You are missing an asterisk after `$b in *$a` though.  I get slightly faster results for `[[ $b == *$a* ]]` than for `case` with the bug corrected, but it could depend on other factors too, of course.

Comment: https://ideone.com/5roEVt has my experiment with some additional bugs fixed and tests for a different scenario (where the string is actually not present in the longer string). Results are largely similar; `[[ $b == *$a* ]]` is quick and `case` is almost as quick (and pleasantly POSIX-compatible).

Comment: The conditional expression `[[ $b == *$a* ]]` and the case statement `case $b in *$a):;;esac ` are not equivalent in a no-match condition. Swapping `$a` and `$b` results in exit code 1 for the conditional expression `[[` and exit code 0 for the `case` statement. As per `help case`: Exit Status: Returns the status of the last command executed.
The return status is zero if *no pattern* is matched, which is probably not the expected behavior. To return 1 in the no match condition, it should be: `case $b in *$a*):;; *) false ;; esac`

Answer (score 75):

Bash 4+ examples. Note: not using quotes will cause issues when words contain spaces, etc. Always quote in Bash, IMO.

Here are some examples Bash 4+:

Example 1, check for 'yes' in string (case insensitive):

```
    if [[ "${str,,}" == *"yes"* ]] ;then
```

Example 2, check for 'yes' in string (case insensitive):

```
    if [[ "$(echo "$str" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')" == *"yes"* ]] ;then
```

Example 3, check for 'yes' in string (case sensitive):

```
     if [[ "${str}" == *"yes"* ]] ;then
```

Example 4, check for 'yes' in string (case sensitive):

```
     if [[ "${str}" =~ "yes" ]] ;then
```

Example 5, exact match (case sensitive):

```
     if [[ "${str}" == "yes" ]] ;then
```

Example 6, exact match (case insensitive):

```
     if [[ "${str,,}" == "yes" ]] ;then
```

Example 7, exact match:

```
     if [ "$a" = "$b" ] ;then
```

Example 8, wildcard match .ext (case insensitive):

```
     if echo "$a" | egrep -iq "\.(mp[3-4]|txt|css|jpg|png)" ; then
```

Example 9, use grep on a string case sensitive:

```
     if echo "SomeString" | grep -q "String"; then
```

Example 10, use grep on a string case insensitive:

```
     if echo "SomeString" | grep -iq "string"; then
```

Example 11, use grep on a string case insensitive w/ wildcard:

```
     if echo "SomeString" | grep -iq "Some.*ing"; then
```

Example 12, use doublehash to compare (if variable empty could cause false postitives etc) (case sensitive):

```
     if [[ ! ${str##*$substr*} ]] ;then  #found
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Aaaah - I only understood it after I found out that the two commas in `${str,,}` convert `$str` to lower case. Great solutions / great list!

Comment: Now what to do with `${str}` if I'm testing a variable? Does `${$MYVAR,,}` work? bash says `bad substitution`

Comment: @SamSirry You have a typo in your example remove the second $. It should be ${VAR,,}. Note if that doesn't work then you have an old shell and have to use one of the other options above.

Answer (score 31):

This also works:

```
if printf -- '%s' "$haystack" | egrep -q -- "$needle"
then
  printf "Found needle in haystack"
fi
```

And the negative test is:

```
if ! printf -- '%s' "$haystack" | egrep -q -- "$needle"
then
  echo "Did not find needle in haystack"
fi
```

I suppose this style is a bit more classic -- less dependent upon features of Bash shell.

The `--` argument is pure POSIX paranoia, used to protected against input strings similar to options, such as `--abc` or `-a`.

Note: In a tight loop this code will be *much* slower than using internal Bash shell features, as one (or two) separate processes will be created and connected via pipes.

Comment: ...but the OP doesn't say which _version_ of bash; e.g., older bash's (such as solaris frequently has) may not include these newer bash features. (I've run into this exact problem (bash pattern matching not implemented) on solaris w/ bash 2.0)

Comment: `echo` is unportable, you should be using `printf '%s' "$haystack` instead.

Comment: @nyuszika7h: I was not away `echo` is unportable.  Will `/bin/echo` work?

Comment: Nope, just avoid `echo` altogether for anything but literal text without escapes that doesn't start with a `-`. It may work for you, but it's not portable. Even bash's `echo` will behave differently depending on whether the `xpg_echo` option is set. **P.S.:** I forgot to close the double quote in my previous comment.

Comment: @nyuszika7h: Do you know if `printf --  <anything>` is portable or only `printf  <anything>`?  Out of habit, I used `printf -- <anything>` to be safe.

Comment: @kevinarpe I'm not sure, `--` is not listed in the [POSIX spec for `printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html), but you should use `printf '%s' "$anything"` anyway, to avoid issues if `$anything` contains a `%` character.

Comment: @nyuszika7h: Regarding support for `--`, I found this POSIX spec for `getopt()`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html.  Do you think it is safe to assume that if `printf` is POSIX defined / compatible, then `--` will also be supported?

Comment: @kevinarpe Based on that, it probably is.

Answer (score 27):

As [Paul mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-bash/25535717#25535717) in his performance comparison:

```
if echo "abcdefg" | grep -q "bcdef"; then
    echo "String contains is true."
else
    echo "String contains is not true."
fi
```

This is POSIX compliant like the 'case "$string" in' [the answer provided by Marcus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-bash/229585#229585), but it is slightly easier to read than the case statement answer. Also note that this will be much much slower than using a case statement. As Paul pointed out, don't use it in a loop.

Comment: And it's the only one that actually works in modern GNU bash (5.x)

Answer (score 20):

How about this:

```
text="   <tag>bmnmn</tag>  "
if [[ "$text" =~ "<tag>" ]]; then
   echo "matched"
else
   echo "not matched"
fi
```

Comment: =~ is for regexp matching, hence too powerful for the OP's purpose.

Answer (score 20):

Accepted answer is correct but it is hard to read and understand.
For problems related to searching you should always use the *$needle in a $haystack* idiom.
Since its *suggested edit queue is full*, I post this:

```sh
haystack='There are needles here.'
if [[ "$haystack" == *"needle"* ]]; then
    echo "It's there!"
fi
```

Comment: It must be mentioned that this only works under `bash`, and when this is used in a script file, it must start with the line `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 12):

```
[[ $string == *foo* ]] && echo "It's there" || echo "Couldn't find"
```

Comment: I will add that the `echo "Couldn't find` statement at the end is a nice trick to return 0 exit statuses for these matching commands.

Comment: @nicodjimenez you can not target exit status any more with this solution. Exit status is swallowed up by the status messages ...

Comment: That's exactly what I meant... If you don't have `|| echo "Couldn't find"` then you will return an error exit status if there is no match, which you might not want if you're running a CI pipeline for example where you want all commands to return non error exit statuses

Answer (score 11):

One is:

```
[ $(expr $mystring : ".*${search}.*") -ne 0 ] && echo 'yes' ||  echo 'no'
```

Comment: `expr` is one of those swiss-army-knife utilities that can usually do whatever it is you need to do, once you figure out how to do it, but once implemented, you can never remember why or how it's doing what it's doing, so you never touch it again, and hope that it never stops doing what it's doing.

Comment: @AloisMahdal I never down-voted, I'm just postulating on why downvotes were given. A cautionary comment. I do use `expr`, on rare occasion, when portability prevents using bash (eg., inconsistent behavior across older versions), tr (inconsistent everywhere) or sed (sometimes too slow). But from personal experience, whenever re-reading these `expr`-isms, I have to go back to the man page. So, I would just comment that every usage of `expr` be commented...

Comment: There was a time when all you had was the original Bourne shell. It lacked some commonly required features, so tools like `expr` and `test` were implemented to perform them. In this day and age, there are usually better tools, many of them built into any modern shell. I guess `test` is still hanging in there, but nobody seems to be missing `expr`.

Comment: Upvoting since I needed something that worked in Bourne shell, and everything else appears to be bash-specific.

Comment: `expr: syntax error: unexpected argument ‘.*.*’` `bash: [: -ne: unary operator expected
`

Comment: This is a very complicated way to accomplish something simple.

Answer (score 11):

[This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/229606/65706) was the only one to trap space and dash characters:

```
# For null cmd arguments checking   
to_check=' -t'
space_n_dash_chars=' -'
[[ $to_check == *"$space_n_dash_chars"* ]] && echo found
```

Comment: It is an answer to this same question.

Answer (score 7):

Since the [POSIX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829613/how-do-you-tell-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-unix-shell-scripting)/BusyBox question is closed without providing the right answer (IMHO), I'll post an answer here.

**The shortest possible answer is:**

```
[ ${_string_##*$_substring_*} ] || echo Substring found!
```

*or*

```
[ "${_string_##*$_substring_*}" ] || echo 'Substring found!'
```

Note that the ***double hash*** is **obligatory** with some shells (`ash`). Above will evaluate `[ stringvalue ]` when the substring is not found. It returns no error. When the substring is found the result is empty and it evaluates `[  ]`. This will throw error code 1 since the string is completely substituted (due to `*`).

**The shortest more common syntax:**

```
[ -z "${_string_##*$_substring_*}" ] && echo 'Substring found!'
```

*or*

```
[ -n "${_string_##*$_substring_*}" ] || echo 'Substring found!'
```

**Another one:**

```
[ "${_string_##$_substring_}" != "$_string_" ] && echo 'Substring found!'
```

*or*

```
[ "${_string_##$_substring_}" = "$_string_" ] || echo 'Substring found!'
```

Note the *single* equal sign!

Answer (score 6):

My *.bash_profile* file and how I used grep:

If the PATH environment variable includes my two `bin` directories, don't append them,

```
# .bash_profile
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

U=~/.local.bin:~/bin

if ! echo "$PATH" | grep -q "home"; then
    export PATH=$PATH:${U}
fi
```

Comment: upvote. why bother to learn how Bash does it when grep, far more powerful, is more than likely going to be available. also extend it a bit further by matching against a list of patterns: `grep -q -E 'pattern1|...|patternN'`.

Answer (score 6):

Extension of the question answered here *[How do you tell if a string contains another string in POSIX sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829613/how-do-you-tell-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-posix-sh/8811800#8811800)*:

This solution works with special characters:

```
# contains(string, substring)
#
# Returns 0 if the specified string contains the specified substring,
# otherwise returns 1.
contains() {
    string="$1"
    substring="$2"

    if echo "$string" | $(type -p ggrep grep | head -1) -F -- "$substring" >/dev/null; then
        return 0    # $substring is in $string
    else
        return 1    # $substring is not in $string
    fi
}

contains "abcd" "e" || echo "abcd does not contain e"
contains "abcd" "ab" && echo "abcd contains ab"
contains "abcd" "bc" && echo "abcd contains bc"
contains "abcd" "cd" && echo "abcd contains cd"
contains "abcd" "abcd" && echo "abcd contains abcd"
contains "" "" && echo "empty string contains empty string"
contains "a" "" && echo "a contains empty string"
contains "" "a" || echo "empty string does not contain a"
contains "abcd efgh" "cd ef" && echo "abcd efgh contains cd ef"
contains "abcd efgh" " " && echo "abcd efgh contains a space"

contains "abcd [efg] hij" "[efg]" && echo "abcd [efg] hij contains [efg]"
contains "abcd [efg] hij" "[effg]" || echo "abcd [efg] hij does not contain [effg]"

contains "abcd *efg* hij" "*efg*" && echo "abcd *efg* hij contains *efg*"
contains "abcd *efg* hij" "d *efg* h" && echo "abcd *efg* hij contains d *efg* h"
contains "abcd *efg* hij" "*effg*" || echo "abcd *efg* hij does not contain *effg*"
```

Comment: The test `contains "-n" "n"` doesn't work here, because `echo -n` will swallow the `-n` as an option! A popular fix for that is to use `printf "%s\n" "$string"` instead.

Comment: I have fixed my answer that you linked so that it now works with special characters. As @midnite pointed out, all it needed was doublequotes around the substring when using POSIX substring parameter expansion. I also stole a few of your test cases. Thanks, Alex.

Answer (score 6):

The generic **needle haystack** example is following with **variables**

```
#!/bin/bash

needle="a_needle"
haystack="a_needle another_needle a_third_needle"
if [[ $haystack == *"$needle"* ]]; then
    echo "needle found"
else
    echo "needle NOT found"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

`grep -q` is useful for this purpose.

The same using `awk`:

```
string="unix-bash 2389"
character="@"
printf '%s' "$string" | awk -vc="$character" '{ if (gsub(c, "")) { print "Found" } else { print "Not Found" } }'
```

Output:

> Not Found

```
string="unix-bash 2389"
character="-"
printf '%s' "$string" | awk -vc="$character" '{ if (gsub(c, "")) { print "Found" } else { print "Not Found" } }'
```

Output:

> Found

Original source: http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2008/06/bash-search-letter-in-string-awk.html

Comment: `echo` is unportable, you should be using `printf '%s' "$string"` instead. I'm editing the answer because the user doesn't appear to exist anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I found to need this functionality quite frequently, so I'm using a home-made shell function in my `.bashrc` like this which allows me to reuse it as often as I need to, with an easy to remember name:

```
function stringinstring()
{
    case "$2" in
       *"$1"*)
          return 0
       ;;
    esac
    return 1
}
```

To test if `$string1` (say, *abc*) is contained in `$string2` (say, *123abcABC*) I just need to run `stringinstring "$string1" "$string2"` and check for the return value, for example

```
stringinstring "$str1" "$str2"  &&  echo YES  ||  echo NO
```

Comment: [[ "$str" == *$substr* ]] && echo YES || echo NO

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `x` hack is only required for **very** old shells.

Comment: The proper -- and immediately recognizable -- name for your function would be `strstr()` :-)

Answer (score 5):

I like sed.

```
substr="foo"
nonsub="$(echo "$string" | sed "s/$substr//")"
hassub=0 ; [ "$string" != "$nonsub" ] && hassub=1
```

Edit, Logic:

- Use sed to remove instance of substring from string
- If new string differs from old string, substring exists

Answer (score 5):

```sh
case $string in (*foo*)
  # Do stuff
esac
```

This is the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/229585/11267590. But simple style and also POSIX Compliant.

Answer (score 4):

Exact word match:

```
string='My long string'
exactSearch='long'

if grep -E -q "\b${exactSearch}\b" <<<${string} >/dev/null 2>&1
  then
    echo "It's there"
  fi
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a logic *&&* to be more compact

```
#!/bin/bash

# NO MATCH EXAMPLE
string="test"
[[ "$string" == *"foo"* ]] && {
        echo "YES"
}

# MATCH EXAMPLE
string="tefoost"
[[ "$string" == *"foo"* ]] && {
        echo "YES"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this function (one dependency not included but obvious). It passes the tests shown below. If the function returns a value > 0 then the string was found. You could just as easily return 1 or 0 instead.

````
function str_instr {
   # Return position of ```str``` within ```string```.
   # >>> str_instr "str" "string"
   # str: String to search for.
   # string: String to search.
   typeset str string x
   # Behavior here is not the same in bash vs ksh unless we escape special characters.
   str="$(str_escape_special_characters "${1}")"
   string="${2}"
   x="${string%%$str*}"
   if [[ "${x}" != "${string}" ]]; then
      echo "${#x} + 1" | bc -l
   else
      echo 0
   fi
}

function test_str_instr {
   str_instr "(" "'foo@host (dev,web)'" | assert_eq 11
   str_instr ")" "'foo@host (dev,web)'" | assert_eq 19
   str_instr "[" "'foo@host [dev,web]'" | assert_eq 11
   str_instr "]" "'foo@host [dev,web]'" | assert_eq 19
   str_instr "a" "abc" | assert_eq 1
   str_instr "z" "abc" | assert_eq 0
   str_instr "Eggs" "Green Eggs And Ham" | assert_eq 7
   str_instr "a" "" | assert_eq 0
   str_instr "" "" | assert_eq 0
   str_instr " " "Green Eggs" | assert_eq 6
   str_instr " " " Green "  | assert_eq 1
}
````

Comment: The suspense! What *is* the dependency?

Comment: The "str_escape_special_characters" function. It is in GitHub arcshell_str.sh file. arcshell.io will get you there.

Comment: `str_escape_special_characters` appears to have become `str_escape`. see `arcshell_str.sh` @ [arclogicsoftware/arcshell](https://github.com/arclogicsoftware/arcshell/blob/master/sh/core/arcshell_str.sh)

Answer (score 0):

```
msg="message"

function check {
    echo $msg | egrep [abc] 1> /dev/null

    if [ $? -ne 1 ];
    then 
        echo "found" 
    else 
        echo "not found" 
    fi
}

check
```

This will find any occurance of a or b or c

Answer (score 0):

With [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/):

```
string='My long string'
echo $string | jq -Rr 'select(contains("long"))|"It is there"'
```

The hardest thing in jq is to print the single quote:

```
echo $string | jq --arg quote "'" -Rr 'select(contains("long"))|"It\($quote)s there"'
```

Using jq just to check the condition:

```
if jq -Re 'select(contains("long"))|halt' <<< $string; then
    echo "It's there!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the POSIX variant but with `sed`:

```
string="My string"
pattern="string"

if [ "${string}" != "$(printf '%s' "${string}" | sed 's/'"${pattern}"'//g')" ]; then
 echo "It's there!"; 
fi
```

Some explanation:

`sed 's/'"${pattern}"'//g'` strips the pattern of the `${string}`.
So, it will look this way:

```
if [ "My string" != "My " ];
```

They are not equal and it's `true`, so it means that the pattern was there.

If you use a different pattern like `pattern="foo"`, the equation will be:

```
if [ "My string" != "My string" ];
```

Because `sed` will not strip anything in this case and it will produce `false`.

It still looks clumsy but this option will work in many shells like dash, zsh and not only bash.

Answer (score -4):

Try oobash.

It is an OO-style string library for Bash 4. It has support for German umlauts. It is written in Bash.

Many functions are available:

```
base64Decode
base64Encode
capitalize
center
charAt
concat
contains
count
endsWith
equals
equalsIgnoreCase
reverse
hashCode
indexOf
isAlnum
isAlpha
isAscii
isDigit
isEmpty
isHexDigit
isLowerCase
isSpace
isPrintable
isUpperCase
isVisible
lastIndexOf
length
matches
replaceAll
replaceFirst
startsWith
substring
swapCase
toLowerCase
toString
toUpperCase
trim
zfill
```

Look at the *contains* example:

```
[Desktop]$ String a testXccc
[Desktop]$ a.contains tX
true
[Desktop]$ a.contains XtX
false
```

[oobash is available at Sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/oobash/).