# How to check if a string has spaces in Bash shell

Tags: string, bash, shell, if-statement

Say a string might be like `"a b '' c '' d"`. How can I check that there is single/double quote and space contained in the string?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you're trying to, say, check for an "invalid" file name, you could instead fix the script to support file names with spaces or quotes. For example.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to know that: a) there is a single/double quote around a space b) a single/double quote along with a space c) something altogether different from that?

Comment: Just to check if a string has any single quote and if it has any space

Comment: To check if string has ONLY spaces, tabs, or new lines, try: `[[ $string = *[$" \t\n"]* ]]`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
case "$var" in  
     *\ * )
           echo "match"
          ;;
       *)
           echo "no match"
           ;;
esac
```

Comment: I'm nitpicking, but you don't need to quote $var.

Comment: @Idelic, what if $var was unset?

Comment: That's perfectly ok without quotes, will print "no match".

Comment: Thanks for quoting it and setting a good example for scripts in general, even though it's not strictly necessary in this particular instance.

Comment: This doesn't detect tabs etc.

Comment: @Mehrdad just add catching-conditions like "\t" ), etc.

Comment: @Juergen: yeah I was I was looking for a snippet that would do that and I thought the bizarre whitespacing in this one might somehow be doing that, and was just disappointed to see otherwise. :/

Comment: @Mehrdad: lets just be lazy and convert whitespace-characters to spaces: https://superuser.com/a/112837/722736

Comment: @Juergen: It's easy with an external program... I was trying to do it in just Bash (ideally in a POSIX-compliant way) since calling external processes can be pretty slow in comparison.

Answer (score 42):

You can use regular expressions in bash:

```
string="a b '' c '' d"
if [[ "$string" =~ \ |\' ]]    #  slightly more readable: if [[ "$string" =~ ( |\') ]]
then
   echo "Matches"
else
   echo "No matches"
fi
```

**Edit:**

For reasons obvious above, it's better to put the regex in a variable:

```
pattern=" |'"
if [[ $string =~ $pattern ]]
```

And quotes aren't necessary inside double square brackets. They can't be used on the right or the regex is changed to a literal string.

Comment: cleanest one IMO, for me I also added tab but looks a little funky as I had to throw the dollar-quote in there  `pattern=" |'"$'|\t'` - is there a cleaner way?

Comment: @nhed: In the case of single characters, you can use a character pattern instead of the pipe character alternation. This might be slightly less ugly: `pattern=$'[ \'\t]'`. You could also use a variable: `tab=$'\t'; pattern=" |'|$tab"` or a literal tab (which isn't good for readability) by typing it in using Ctrl-V-Tab.

Answer (score 35):

You could do this, without the need for any backslashes or external commands:

```
# string matching

if [[ $string = *" "* ]]; then
  echo "string contains one or more spaces"
else
  echo "string doesn't contain spaces"
fi

# regex matching

re="[[:space:]]+"
if [[ $string =~ $re ]]; then
  echo "string contains one or more spaces"
else
  echo "string doesn't contain spaces"
fi
```

Based on this [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25535717/6862601), the string match is much faster than the regex one.

---

Related:

- [How to check if a string contains a substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229551/6862601)

Comment: Best most current answer because it specifically answers the question - a space in a string - by providing two options that are portable and very easy to understand during a code review. Please people, like @codeforester, keep it simple; the best software always is.

Comment: The regex version is more general, since it also finds \t and \n and \r. [:space:] "Whitespace characters such as space, form-feed, newline,carriage return, horizontal tab, and vertical tab" https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/oracle-regular-expressions/0596006012/re08.html

Answer (score 9):

```
[[ "$str" = "${str%[[:space:]]*}" ]] && echo "no spaces" || echo "has spaces"
```

Comment: note that this doesn't detect tabs or newlines, for those who are curious

Answer (score 8):

```
string="a b '' c '' d"
if [ "$string" == "${string//[\' ]/}" ]
then 
   echo did not contain space or single quote
else
   echo did contain space or single quote
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

The portable way to do this is with `grep`:

```
S="a b '' c '' d"
if echo $S | grep -E '[ "]' >/dev/null
then
  echo "It's a match"
fi
```

...a bit ugly, but guaranteed to work everywhere.

Comment: With `-q` option in grep, the `>/dev/null` not needed anymore. A bit nicer.

Answer (score 3):

How about an approach similar to:

```
$ A="some string"; echo $A | grep \  | wc -l
1
$ A="somestring"; echo $A | grep \  | wc -l
0
```

?

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
[[ $var == ${var//[ \"]/_} ]] && echo "quotes or spaces not found"
```

or if you like this:

```
if [[ $var == ${var//[ \"]/_} ]] ; then  
   echo "quotes or spaces not found" 
else
   echo "found quotes or spaces"
fi
```

**Explanation:** 
I'm evaluating a comparison between the variable ${var} and the variable ${var} itself after a on-the-fly non-destructive string substitution of all the quotes and spaces with an underscore.

**Examples:**

```
${var// /_}  # Substitute all spaces with underscores
```

The following code substitute all characters between the squared brackets (space and quotes) with an underscore. Note that quotes has to be protected with backslash:

```
${var//[ \"]/_}
```

Comment: I like the use of this syntax, but you've flipped the search and are seeking the opposite of what OP asked for. Should mention `!=`

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo() {
    echo "String: $*"
    SPACES=$(($#-1))
    echo "Spaces: $SPACES"
    QUOTES=0
    for i in $*; do
        if [ "$i" == "'" ]; then
            QUOTES=$((QUOTES+1))
        fi
    done
    echo "Quotes: $QUOTES"
    echo
}

S="string with spaces"
foo $S
S="single' 'quotes"
foo $S
S="single '' quotes"
foo $S
S="single ' ' quotes"
foo $S
```

yields:

```
String: string with spaces
Spaces: 2
Quotes: 0

String: single' 'quotes
Spaces: 1
Quotes: 0

String: single '' quotes
Spaces: 2
Quotes: 0

String: single ' ' quotes
Spaces: 3
Quotes: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I do wonder why nobody mentioned the [:space:] set. Usually your not only interested in detecting the space character. I often need to detect any white space, e.g. TAB. The "grep" example would look like this:

```
$ echo " " | egrep -q "[:space:]" && echo "Has no Whitespace" || echo "Has Whitespace"
Has Whitespace
$ echo "a" | egrep -q "[:space:]" && echo "Has no Whitespace" || echo "Has Whitespace"
Has no Whitespace
```

Comment: For those interested in this solution, my `grep` informs me that `character class syntax is [[:space:]], not [:space:]`. Otherwise, excellent solution!

Comment: Since question is tagged "bash", no need to start up another process just to test a string: `case "$String" in  *[[:space:]]*) echo "match" ;;  esac`