# How to check for whitespace characters using sed or grep in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
if [ $char -eq " " -o $char -eq "" -o $char -eq "   " ]
```

Comment: What do you want to do with that comparison. Are you trying to remove white space from lines in a file?

Comment: No, i just want to skip them

Comment: [How to check if a string has spaces in Bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1473981/608639)

Answer (score 1):

This works for single char variable $char, but note that the post assumes mainly a multi-char variable.

Use:

`if grep -q '\s' <<< "$char"; then ...`

Answer (score 1):

-eq is for numerics.  Also, you should enclose the variable in quotes, such as "$char", not $char

```
#! /bin/sh

A=1
B=" "

if [ "$A" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "eq is for numeric"
fi

if [ "$B" = " " ]; then
    echo "= is for characters"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

-eq for numeric value, for string, use ==

```
if [[ $char == " " || -z $char || $char == "   " ]]; then
```

- -z equivalent ""
- || equivalent -o

regex alternative with recent bash ( 0 or 1 space or 3 spaces ):

```
if [[ $char =~ ^\ {0,1}$ || $char =~ ^\ {3}$ ]] ; then
```

- `\` : space only
- `[[:blank:]]` : space, tab
- `[[:space:]]` : space, tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return
- if you want to match 0 to 3 spaces: `if [[ $char =~ ^\ {0,3}$ ]] ; then`

Answer (score 0):

In bash you can use regex match in `[[]]`

```
if  [[ $char =~ [[:space:]] ]]
```

If you actually want to match a single whitespace character

```
if  [[ $char =~ ^[[:space:]]$ ]]
```

Or single whitespace or nothing

```
if  [[ $char =~ ^[[:space:]]?$ ]]
```

Or only whitespace in a string

```
if  [[ $char =~ ^[[:space:]]+$ ]]
```

Or only whitespace or nothing

```
if  [[ $char =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]]
```

Comment: `char='a a' matches...`

Comment: @kyodev Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @kyodev Not sure what you mean?

Comment: @kyodev Question asks for whitespace, `[[:space:]]` is a character class for whitespace. Note that the code in the question is just what OP tried, not necessarily exactly what they want.