# Jenkins & Grails: Error initializing VM

Tags: linux, grails, jvm, jenkins

I want to use the Grails plugin with Jenkins. But every build fails with this message:

```
[workspace] $ /usr/local/grails-2.1.1/bin/grails clean --non-interactive
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified
Build step 'Build With Grails' marked build as failure
```

When I run the command from console it is executed without this Java error. I tried setting memory usage in GRAILS_OPTS but it still won't work. I'm kind of stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

`cd /opt/grails/bin`

Look for the line that says:

```
GRAILS_OPTS="-server -Xmx718M -Xms718M -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

...and change it to:

```
GRAILS_OPTS="-server -Xmx512m -Xms512m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to manually modify the script in `/usr/share/grails/2.1.1/bin/startGrails` to work around this issue, as that parameter was being passed in by Jenkins in JAVA_OPTS and being set in the GRAILS_OPTS.

First I removed the parameter from the GRAILS_OPTS:

```
GRAILS_OPTS="-server -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

leaving

```
GRAILS_OPTS="-server -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

Then I added [a POSIX compliant `contains` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8811800/16487):

```
#POSIX compliant contains implementation
#Usage string substring
contains() {
    test "${1#*$2}" != "$1"
}
```

And then I added logic to re-add the sizes if they weren't present (b/c I use grails from the command line as well) <sub>the `echo` statements are of course for debugging only</sub>.  Note that this is a change to a delivered file, and may have to be remade if you upgrade Grails.

```
 JAVA_OPTS="$GRAILS_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS $AGENT"
  echo "JAVA_OPTS: $JAVA_OPTS"
  if ! contains "$JAVA_OPTS" -Xms  && ! contains "$JAVA_OPTS" -Xmx
    then
        echo "Setting -Xms"
        JAVA_OPTS="-Xms768M $JAVA_OPTS"
  fi
  if ! contains "$JAVA_OPTS" -Xmx
    then
        echo "Setting -Xmx"
        JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx768M $JAVA_OPTS"
  fi
  echo "JAVA_OPTS: $JAVA_OPTS"
```

Answer (score -1):

What heap size options are you using?  This sounds like you're using the wrong units or leaving them off.  If I do something this I get the same error message:

```
$ JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2048 grails run-app
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified
```

Using `-Xmx2048M` works as expected.