# Linux Shell Script - String Comparison with wildcards

Tags: linux, string, shell, sh

I am trying to see if a string is part of another string in shell script (#!bin/sh).

The code i have now is:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Test scriptje to test string comparison!

testFoo () {
        t1=$1
        t2=$2
        echo "t1: $t1 t2: $t2"
        if [ $t1 == "*$t2*" ]; then
                echo "$t1 and $t2 are equal"
        fi
}

testFoo "bla1" "bla"
```

The result I'm looking for, is that I want to know when "bla" exists in "bla1".

Thanks and kind regards,

UPDATE:
I've tried both the "contains" function as described here: [How do you tell if a string contains another string in Unix shell scripting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829613/how-do-you-tell-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-unix-shell-scripting)

As well as the syntax in [String contains in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash)

However, they seem to be non compatible with normal shell script (bin/sh)...

Help?

Comment: check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash

Comment: Same question and answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829613/how-do-you-tell-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-unix-shell-scripting

Answer (score 81, accepted):

When using `==` or `!=` in bash you can write:

```
if [[ $t1 == *"$t2"* ]]; then
    echo "$t1 and $t2 are equal"
fi
```

Note that the asterisks go on the *outside* of the quotes and that the wildcard pattern *must* be on the right.

For /bin/sh, the `=` operator is for equality only, not pattern matching.  You can use `case` for pattern matching though:

```
case "$t1" in
    *"$t2"*) echo t1 contains t2 ;;
    *) echo t1 does not contain t2 ;;
esac
```

If you're specifically targeting Linux, I would assume the presence of /bin/bash.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Glenn! very much appreciated!
(and it's a linux environment, but very lightweight, and without /bin/bash so i really needed that /bin/sh version! - thanks again!)

Comment: Better than coping with case, use =~ operator: if [[ $t1 =~ %t2* ]]; the echo match; fi

Comment: @lef, for a regular expression, you want `[[ $t1 =~ "$t2" ]]`

Comment: @glenn, right, besides a typo (%t2 instead of $t2), sh actually may not support double brackets [[ ]]

Comment: Omg this is so counter intuitive! Thanks now it makes sense.

Comment: @alex there is not much  that's intuitive about bash

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks I'm only learning, and I made exactly the same mistake as the author of this question, e.g. put the wildcard between speech marks.

Comment: @glenn jackman, hey bud, can you help me how to get my script done? I have trouble in getting the `*856*` as `*` is a wildcard. This is my script: `findFile() { while read -r LINE;
do
     printf "$LINE\n"; 
     grep -il '$LINE' *856*; 
done < /path/to/file.txt
}`

Comment: Notice that order matters: the wilds cards need to be on the right hand side of the comparison... at least from my experience.