# How to check argument equality with '*' wildcard in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, glob

I'm new to bash scripting and I'm writing a script to automatically make a newly created `.sh` file executable. As such, I would want to check if `.sh` is preceded by the only argument provided in order to ensure a valid filename.

However, I'm getting a `[: too many arguments` error when I run `./createExecutableScript.sh asd.sh`.

Initially, I thought it was because `$1` was not wrapped in `"` that caused the error, and therefore added the `"`s in.

I also referred to this question 
([Linux Shell Script - String Comparison with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891491/linux-shell-script-string-comparison-with-wildcards)) and added the `*`s outside of the `"`s.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ "$1" == *".sh" ]
then
    echo "Creating file with name: $1"
else
    echo "Invalid or missing filename!"
fi
```

Comment: Post the content of your script

Comment: @deosha edited to include the script!

Comment: Shellcheck tells you what the problem is. Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the resources, will look at them! @jww

Answer (score 2):

The answer in [Linux Shell Script - String Comparison with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891491/linux-shell-script-string-comparison-with-wildcards) is correct, you need to have double brackets like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [[ "$1" == *".sh" ]]
then
    echo "Creating file with name: $1"
else
    echo "Invalid or missing filename!"
fi
```

Comment: Ah, I got careless there. Marked this question as duplicate. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

So there is no variable as 1. You can do something like `a=$1` and then put `$a` in the `if` statement. What you need is `$($1)` and not `$1`

Comment: In OP's example, `$1` will correctly be `asd.sh`