# Linux /bin/sh check if string contains X

Tags: linux, shell

In a shell script, how can I find out if a string is contained within another string. 
In bash, I would just use =~, but I am not sure how I can do the same in /bin/sh. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you tell if a string contains another string in Unix shell scripting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829613/how-do-you-tell-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-unix-shell-scripting)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a case statement:

```
case "$myvar" in
*string*) echo yes ;;
*       ) echo no ;;
esac
```

All you have to do is substitute `string` for whatever you need.

For example:

```
case "HELLOHELLOHELLO" in
*HELLO* ) echo "Greetings!" ;;
esac
```

Or, to put it another way:

```
string="HELLOHELLOHELLO"
word="HELLO"
case "$string" in
*$word*) echo "Match!" ;;
*      ) echo "No match" ;;
esac
```

Of course, you must be aware that `$word` should not contain magic glob characters unless you intend glob matching.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work

#!/bin/sh
myvar="HELLO"
myothervar="HELLOHELLOHELLO"
case "$myvar" in
*$myothervar*) echo yes ;;
*            ) echo no ;;
esac

Comment: The stars, `*`, either side are significant and *must* be there.

Comment: Contrary to my previous comment (now deleted), it *does* do variable expansion. It's the missing stars that are the problem.

Comment: Also, you have `myvar` and `myothervar` backwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function

```
matches() {
    input="$1"
    pattern="$2"
    echo "$input" | grep -q "$pattern"
}
```

to get regular expression matching. Note: usage is

```
if matches input pattern; then
```

(without the `[ ]`).

Comment: or you could just write `if echo "$input" | grep -q "$pattern"; then`, but that's not really a shell solution.

Comment: @ams naming matters :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try
lookup 'his' in 'This is a test'

```
TEST="This is a test"
if [ "$TEST" != "${TEST/his/}" ]
then
echo "$TEST"
fi
```

Comment: TEST="This is a test";
if [ "$TEST" != ${TEST/his/} ];
then;
echo $TEST;
fi

Comment: I get [: is: unexpected operator/operand

Comment: @user3840020 TEST="This is a test"; if [ "$TEST" != ${TEST/his/} ]; then echo $TEST; f