# Shell script to check if a string contains something

Tags: shell

I have the following shell script.

```
  if [ "$group" == "First*" ]]
  then
            OWNER_EMAIL=first-logs@ginger.com
  elif [ "$group"  == "Second*" ]]
  then
           OWNER_EMAIL=second-team@ginger.com
  fi
```

It does not throw any error , but does not execute the if statement properly if $group contains a First or a Second inside. Can any one tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried `if [ "$group" = "First*" ]]` I think in shell programming one equals sign is enough.

Comment: firstly there is a syntax error you need to use either [ ] or [[ ]] 
secondly if the brackets are just typo then I think you want to use the wildcard * .. but when double quotes are used the wildcard looses it meaning

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you tell if a string contains another string in Unix shell scripting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829613/how-do-you-tell-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-unix-shell-scripting)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes `""` and it is done

```
if [ "$group" == First* ]
then
        OWNER_EMAIL=first-logs@ginger.com
 elif [ "$group"  == Second* ]
 then
       OWNER_EMAIL=second-team@ginger.com
 fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider a `case` statement for efficiency:

```
case "$group" in
First*)
    OWNER_EMAIL=first-logs@ginger.com
    ;;
Second*)
    OWNER_EMAIL=second-team@ginger.com
    ;;
esac
```

You can add `*) ... ;;` as well for default action.

Comment: why is this efficient?

Comment: @user2890683 `case` statements have less runtime overhead than other tests including `[[ ]]`. You also don't call a builtin twice for the test. And case statements are not even in the level of builtins.

Answer (score 0):

When we use double quotes the wildcard character are not retained ... the check condition is looking for a exact "First*" and "Second*" match .

change your code in following way

```
if [[ "$group" == First* ]]
   then
        OWNER_EMAIL=first-logs@ginger.com
   elif [[ "$group"  == Second* ]]
   then
       OWNER_EMAIL=second-team@ginger.com
   fi
```