# How to find and replace special chars within a string in zsh

Tags: replace, zsh

I'm trying to build a `secure copy protocol` quick function.  When I run the command it will work with a single file OR with the entire directory, but as soon as I put a `/*` after the `local_repo` it returns `zsh: no matches found: hackingedu/*`.

If I put the command `scp hackingedu\/\* hackingedu` the command works properly.  I think I'm on the right track, but can't get it to work.

```
contains() {
    string="$1"
    substring="$2"
    if test "${string#*$substring}" != "$string"
    then
        # echo '$substring is in $string'
        return 1    # $substring is in $string
    else
        # echo '$substring is not in $string'
        return 0    # $substring is not in $string
    fi
}


# Quickly scp files in Workspace to Remote
function scp() {
    local_repo="$1"
    remote_repo="$2"

    # find all the `*` and replace with `/*`
    if [ contains $local_repo '*' ]; then
        # replace all instances of * with \*                 <- HOW TO DO
    fi
    command scp -r $LOCAL_REPOS/$local_repo $ALEX_SERVER_UNAME@$ALEX_SERVER_PORT:$ALEX_REMOTE_ROOT_PATH/$remote_repo

    # Description: $1: Local Repo  |  $2:  Remote Repo
    # Define ex: scpp local/path/to/file/or/directory/* remote/path/to/file/or/directory/*
    # Live ex: scpp alexcory/index.php alexcory/index.php
    # Live ex: scpp alexcory/* alexcory/*
    #
    # This Saves you from having long commands that look like this:
    # scp -r ~/Google\ Drive/server/Dev/git\ repositories/hackingedu/* alexander@alexander.com:/home2/alexander/public_html/hackingedu/beta
}
```

Command trying to execute: `scp -r ~/Google\ Drive/server/Dev/git\ repositories/hackingedu/* alexander@alexander.com:/home2/alexander/public_html/hackingedu/beta`

Any ideas on how to find and replace an `*`?  If there's a better way to do this please do tell! :)

If you know how to do this in `bash` I would like your input as well!

**References:**

- [How do you tell if a string contains another string in Unix shell scripting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829613/how-do-you-tell-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-unix-shell-scripting)
- [ZSH Find command replacement](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2014/msg00436.html)
- [ZSH Find command replacement 2](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2014/msg00435.html)
- [Using wildcards in commands with zsh](https://superuser.com/questions/584249/using-wildcards-in-commands-with-zsh#_=_)

Comment: Are you sure that there are any (non-hidden) files in `~/Google\ Drive/server/Dev/git\ repositories/hackingedu/`? The error comes from the shell before the function is even called and it essentially tells you that there are no files there.

Answer (score 0):

You can either prefix your scp call using `noglob` (which will turn off globbing for that command, e.g. `noglob ls *`) or use

```
autoload -U url-quote-magic
zle -N self-insert url-quote-magic
zstyle -e :urlglobber url-other-schema '[[ $words[1] == scp ]] && reply=("*") || reply=(http https ftp)'
```

the above should make zsh auto quote `*` when you use `scp`.

[...]

BTW, in any case, you should learn that you can easily quote special characters using `${(q)variable_name}`, e.g.

```
% foo='*&$%normal_chars'
% echo $foo
*&$%normal_chars
% echo ${(q)foo}
\*\&\$%normal_chars
```