# While loop in .sh file with condition to compare if a string contains a substring

Tags: bash, shell

I have a .sh file in which I have written the following function. The command that calls this function will have the arguments- **file1.war**, **file2.war** ... **fileN.war** and other arguments.

I want to do a certain operation to the `.war` files and something else for the arguments after it. So I have written a while loop that will run till the arguments are `.war` files, and when an argument is encountered without .`war` extention, it will exit the loop and run the code below it for the rest of the arguments.

Here is the function in .sh file :

```
copyWarFiles()
{
downloadFileName=$1
    shift 1
extn=".war"
while [ condition ]
do      
        log "war file $downloadFileName .."
         #some operation..
        downloadFileName=$1
        shift 1
done
#operations for the rest of the arguments...
}
```

What should I give as condition that will return true if $downloadFileName ends with `.war`? I tried giving 
`$downloadFileName==*".war"` (following the accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash) ) 
and I also tried this :

```
`test "${downloadFileName#*$extn}" != "$downloadFileName"`
```

(following the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829613/how-do-you-tell-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-unix-shell-scripting)) where **extn** is another variable I declared and assigned to `.war`.

But in both the cases, I see that it never enters the while loop. I think I have gone wrong with the syntax or something. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What should I give as condition that will return true if $downloadFileName ends with ".war"? I tried giving `$downloadFileName==*".war"` […]

Bash, unlike typical programming languages, doesn't recognize `==` as a special operator; it's just yet another argument to the `[` command. So you need to set it off with spaces.

Also, the `[` command doesn't support having a pattern on the right-hand-side of `==`; you need to use the special `[[ ... ]]` notation.

So:

```
while [[ $downloadFileName == *".war" ]]
```

Note, though, that the double-quotes around `.war` don't actually have any effect: none of the characters in `.war` are special characters that need to be quoted. Conversely, it's a best practice to always put variable expansions in double-quotes, in case the variables contain special characters. (`[[` actually negates most of the problematic behaviors, but it's just a good habit to be in.)

So:

```
while [[ "$downloadFileName" == *.war ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
check=`echo $downloadFile | grep '\.war'`
if [ -n "$check" ]; then
    echo $downloadFile ends in .war
fi
```