# Bash script working locally but returning syntax error in CI

Tags: bash, shell, sh, gitlab-ci

On my gitlab CI I am running the following simple script (.gitlab-ci.yml):

```
STR=$(cat $FILE)
if grep -q "substring" <<< "$STR"; then echo "ok"; fi
```

Unfortunatley this gives me the error

```
/bin/sh: eval: line 100: syntax error: unexpected redirection
```

Running the same command locally as a script is working as expected:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE="./file.txt"
STR=$(cat $FILE)

if grep -q "substring" <<< "$STR"; then
    echo "ok"
fi
```

The file has the content:

```
This has a substring somewhere
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/bin/sh` is not `bash` and `<<<` is a bash extension not available on every shell. Install bash, change shebang to `/bin/bash` and make sure the script is run under bash or use posix compatible syntax `printf "%s\n" "$str" | grep...`

Note: UPPER CASE VARIABLES are by convention reserved for exported variables, like `IFS` `COLUMNS` `PWD` `UID` `EUID` `LINES` etc. Use lower case variables in your scripts.

Comment: Im running this in a alpine image. I think there is no bash but sh. How can I check for substring in sh?

Comment: `or use posix compatible syntax printf "%s\n" "$str" | grep...` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829613/how-do-you-tell-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-posix-sh I meant `if printf "%s\n" "$str" | grep -q somehthing; then`.