# Check an array of strings against another array - Bash

Tags: arrays, string, bash, sh, string-comparison

I have two lists.

I have to check if there is a tar.gz which name contains a substring like aa or ab and so on.
I'm using this little function:
[How do you tell if a string contains another string in POSIX sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829613/how-do-you-tell-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-posix-sh)

```
local=(aa ab ac ad ae)
remote=(ab.tar.gz ac.tar.gz ad.tar.gz ae.tar.gz af.tar.gz)

contains() { test -n "$1" || test -z "$2" && test -z "${1##*"$2"*}"; }
for le in "${local[@]}"; do
    for re in "${remote[@]}"; do
        contains "$re" "$le" && to_dl+=("$re")
    done
done
```

This works well for me, but I need a second list, which contains the elements of the local list, that don't have a match in the remote list.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the list? where is the second list?

Comment: please update the question with the current output and the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small modification to OP's current code:

```
local=(aa ab ac ad ae)
remote=(ab.tar.gz ac.tar.gz ad.tar.gz ae.tar.gz af.tar.gz)

unset to_dl not_there           # or: to_dl=() not_there=()

contains() { test -n "$1" || test -z "$2" && test -z "${1##*"$2"*}"; }

for le in "${local[@]}"
do
    for re in "${remote[@]}"
    do
        contains "$re" "$le" && { to_dl+=("$re"); continue 2; }
    done
    not_there+=("$le")
done
```

Where:

- `continue 2` - if we find a match then skip to the next substring (`le`) in the list
- `not_there+=("$le")` - if inner loop finds no matches then save the substring in a different array

Results:

```
$ typeset -p to_dl not_there
declare -a to_dl=([0]="ab.tar.gz" [1]="ac.tar.gz" [2]="ad.tar.gz" [3]="ae.tar.gz")
declare -a not_there=([0]="aa")
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider just `grep -f`.

```
$ tmp=$(printf "%s\n" "${remote[@]}" | grep -Ff <(printf "%s\n" "${local[@]}"))
$ readarray -t to_dl <<<"$tmp"
$ declare -p to_dl
declare -a to_dl=([0]="ab.tar.gz" [1]="ac.tar.gz" [2]="ad.tar.gz" [3]="ae.tar.gz")
```

> I need a second list, which contains the elements of the local list, that don't have a match in the remote list.

Use `grep -v`.

In your code, just use `if`. Overall, prefer `if` over any `&&`.

```
if contains "$re" "$le"; then
    to_dl+=("$re")
else
    secondlist+=("$re")
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, @KamilCuk.  

Maybe my example or explanation is bad.  
`local=(aa ab ac ad ae ag)
remote=(ab.tar.gz ac.tar.gz ad.tar.gz ae.tar.gz af.tar.gz)`  
Result should be:  
`to_dl=(ab.tar.gz ac.tar.gz ad.tar.gz ae.tar.gz)  
not_there=(aa ag)`