# If else statement in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I tried lot of ways to match a string but my if statement don't work. I want to test if the first parameter is equal to his reverse.

> For example if [ $1 = "something" ] may work but i don't know how to do it if i'm using
>   my reverse variable

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo "la string en parametre" ${1}
 reverse= echo -n $1 | rev
 if [[ $1=reverse ]]; then
 echo "est pas un palindrome"
 else
 echo "est un palindrome"
 fi
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare two string variables in an 'if' statement in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277665/how-do-i-compare-two-string-variables-in-an-if-statement-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this doesn't work:

```
reverse= echo -n $1 | rev
```

Use command substitution:

```
reverse=$( echo -n "$1" | rev )
```

Second, this won't work:

```
if [[ $1=reverse ]]; then
```

There must be spaces around `=` and to access a variable, you need a dollar sign:

```
if [[ $1 = $reverse ]]; then
```

In sum, try:

```
echo "la string en parametre: '$1'"
reverse=$( echo -n "$1" | rev )
if [[ $1 = $reverse ]]; then
    echo "est un palindrome"
else
    echo "est pas un palindrome"
fi
```