# bash if statement issue

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, scripting

Would someone mind giving me a hand with the following IF Statement?

read -e -p "Would you like to reboot now?: " -i " " REBOOT

```
if $REBOOT = 'yes' ; then
   echo 'System will now reboot'
   shutdown -r now
else $REBOOT != 'yes'
   echo 'You have chosen to reboot later'
fi
```

If I enter 'yes' I get the following as an endless result

```
= yes
= yes
= yes
...
= yes
```

And if I enter 'no' I get the following:

```
./test.sh: line 7: no: command not found
./test.sh: line 10: no: command not found
You have chosen to reboot later
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare two string variables in an 'if' statement in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277665/how-do-i-compare-two-string-variables-in-an-if-statement-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you're getting is the same as if you typed:

```
yes = 'yes'
```

To denote a comparison, you should use brackets on the if. It should be:

```
if [ $REBOOT = 'yes' ] ; then
```

plus you have a second condition on the else without another if. You don't need it anyway

Total code should be:

```
if [ $REBOOT = 'yes' ] ; then
   echo 'System will now reboot'
   shutdown -r now
else
   echo 'You have chosen to reboot later'
fi
```