# Comparing long strings with spaces

Tags: bash

I'm trying to compare two strings, which are identical as I can see in the log of debugging the next lines:

```
echo "line: $line"
echo "fingerPrints:$i ${fingerPrints[$i]}"

31 + echo 'line: DCD0 5B71 EAB9 4199 527F 44AC DB6B 8C1F 96D8 BF6D'  
32 + echo 'fingerPrints:1 DCD0 5B71 EAB9 4199 527F 44AC DB6B 8C1F 96D8 BF6D'
```

But when I try a line after to compare those strings,

```
if ["$line" ne "${fingerPrints[$i]}"]; then
```

this is what's happening:

```
33 + '[DCD0 5B71 EAB9 4199 527F 44AC DB6B 8C1F 96D8 BF6D' ne
'DCD0 5B71 EAB9 4199 527F 44AC DB6B 8C1F 96D8 BF6D]' ./gentoo-stage.sh:

line 33: [DCD0 5B71 EAB9 4199 527F 44AC DB6B 8C1F 96D8 BF6D: command not found
```

I am not trying to check if one string contains the other, just if they are euqal.

Same results when I try `!=` instead of `ne`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare two string variables in an 'if' statement in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277665/how-do-i-compare-two-string-variables-in-an-if-statement-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put a space after `[` and before `]`. So instead of:

> ```
> if ["$line" ne "${fingerPrints[$i]}"]; then
> ```

Write like this:

```
if [ "$line" ne "${fingerPrints[$i]}" ]; then
```

And "ne" is not an operator. You probably meant `!=` there:

```
if [ "$line" != "${fingerPrints[$i]}" ]; then
```

Btw `-ne` is used for comparing integer expressions, and you're comparing strings, so `!=` is really the only operator that makes sense here.