# How do I use the output of an ls command in an if statement in a bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

I want to check if only one instance of a file exists before going on to process that file.

I can check how many instances exist using this command:

```
ls -l $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_FILE_PREFIX}cons*.csv.gz | wc -l;
```

However, when I go to use this within an if statement, I am warned that the `ls: command not found`.

```
if [ls -l $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_FILE_PREFIX}cons*.csv.gz | wc -l = '1']
 then
 echo "Only 1 File Exists";
fi
```

I've tried adding a semicolon at the end of the ls command and enclosing it in square brackets - neither of these yielded any results.

I very rarely have to do any Shell scripting, and I suspect this a very basic error, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You really don't want to use `ls` in scripts at all. Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: The error is `[ls: command not found` because `[ls` is indeed not a valid command; see also [Why should there be spaces around '[' and '\]' in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-there-be-spaces-around-and-in-bash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
if [ $(ls $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_FILE_PREFIX}cons*.csv.gz 2>/dev/null | wc -l) == 1 ]
 then
 echo "Only 1 File Exists";
fi
```

evaluates the result and compares with double equals. Also, put spaces before and after square brackets.

Also, filter out the case where no file matches (avoids `no such file or directory` error)

Note: you don't even need the `-l` option. When outputting to a non-interactive terminal (i.e a file or a pipe), `ls` issues 1 line per file. You can also force it with `-C1` option. You'll gain 3 nanoseconds (at least :)) not performing extra `stat` calls to get date, size, etc.. which are not needed.

Comment: Top spot with the filtering of no matches - thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Change your `if` condition as below:

```
if [ "$(ls -l $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_FILE_PREFIX}cons*.csv.gz | wc -l)" = "1" ]
```

- There need to be a space after `[` and before `]`
- Running the command within `$()` will invoke a subshell and run the command.
- Placing the `$()` within double-quotes will avoid error thrown in case of empty output.

Comment: filtering the error when output is empty did not work for me (using old MSYS bash 3, maybe it's bash 4 only, and if it is it would be useful to specify it)

Answer (score 2):

You will want to do something like this:

```
if [[ $(ls -l $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_FILE_PREFIX}cons*.csv.gz | wc -l) == '1' ]]; then
  # Something
fi
```

The $(command) syntax captures the output. I am not sure if the equal comparison is correct thought, but according to this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277665/how-do-i-compare-two-string-variables-in-an-if-statement-in-bash) it is.

Comment: have you tested that?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No I haven't but it usually works for me this way. I am a beginner when it comes to this stuff, but learning is a wonderful thing!

Answer (score 2):

Few subtleties that the previous answers didn't cover:

```
if [ "$(ls -1d $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_FILE_PREFIX}cons*.csv.gz 2>/dev/null | wc -l)" -eq 1 ]; then 
  echo 'Only 1 file';
fi
```

First use `-1d` (one, dee) will do 2 things: it won't expand directories (if you have a directory name ending in .csv.gz for some odd reason) and will only display 1 entry per line with no (total header) header or other output that is uneeded.  Redirecting stderr to `/dev/null` will prevent the `ls: cannot access z*: No such file or directory`message.

Finally, you should either use `=` or `-eq` as `==` is not compatible with zsh if using the single `[` test operator (if you care about bash/zsh compatibility).  Also BSD/OSX `wc` puts some leading space in the output so you might want to pipe to `awk` to strip out so the comparison can be made.

Answer (score 1):

I hope "-l" option is not needed for checking the presence of files. We can also use command substitution to get the same result.

```
#!/bin/bash    
if [ `ls -l $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_FILE_PREFIX}cons*.csv.gz | wc -l` -eq 1 ];then
    echo "One exists"
fi
```

Comment: @paulfrith So do me `alias l='ls -lrth'` :-)