# bash if/else compare variable and string parameter

Tags: bash

Can someone explain how to correctly do an if/else in bash when comparing a parameter to a string? In detail please, I tried to combine elements of these websites [1](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-if-statement-examples) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash/229606#229606) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277665/how-do-i-compare-two-string-variables-in-an-if-statement-in-bash) but I don't know what went wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash
sellx=125
selly=154 #top
itemwidth=10

#takes in two params $1=buy/sell   $2=number in buy or sell
ModifyItem(){
    if [["$1"=="sell"]] 
    then
        xdotool mousemove "$sellx" "$(($selly+$2*$itemwidth))";
    else
        echo "nope";
    fi
}

ModifyItem sell 2
```

Comment: Have you tried `if [ $1 = "sell" ] then`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespace is important; you need to separate the `==` operator from its arguments, and you need to separate the brackets from the condition.

```
if [[ "$1" == "sell" ]]
```