# How to compare two things in bash?

Tags: bash

I need to compare a to z.

```
if[$a -eq $z]
then echo "something"
else echo "nothing"
fi
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: You need spaces around `[` and `]`.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277665/how-do-i-compare-two-string-variables-in-an-if-statement-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need spaces to separate `[` from the `if` command, and to separate it from its arguments.

```
if [ "$a" -eq "$z" ]
```

Note also that `-eq` is for comparing numeric values. If the variables contain strings, you should use `=`.