# Shell scripting while loop error

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
a=0
while ["$a" -lt 10]
do
a=`expr "$a" + 1`
echo $a
done
```

This is the error:

```
a.sh: 3: a.sh: [0: not found
```

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ is very handy for such typos

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare two string variables in an 'if' statement in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277665/how-do-i-compare-two-string-variables-in-an-if-statement-in-bash), or [Why should there be a space after '\[' and before '\]' in a Bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-there-be-a-space-after-and-before-in-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

you need to keep spaces around your brackets:

```
while [ "$a" -lt 10 ]
```

since bash interpretes strings; it uses spaces to separate words. When you write `["$a"`; then bash reads: `[0` (after $a is replaced with 0)

Comment: Sorry, deleted duplicate answer!