# Find and replace string in associative array in bash

Tags: bash, hash, replace

I have an associative array that I create from a file for getting failed login attemps per user.  The array looks like this:

```
declare -Ai hash

while read -r -a array; do
    [[ "${array[5]} ${array[6]}" == "Failed password" ]] && hash[${array[8]}]+=1
done < $FILEPATH
```

One of the users that comes up is listed as `invalid` and I'd like to change the string to `UNKNOWN`. So how do I iterate over the hash and find the string I need and replace its value?

Something like this?

```
for i in "${!hash[@]}"; do
    # (if $i == 'invalid', replace with 'UNKNOWN') ??
done
```

What would be the syntax for that replace?

Comment: you want to compare `"${array[8]}"` to "invalid", and if they're the same, set `array[8]` the string "UNKNOWN"? Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277665/how-do-i-compare-two-string-variables-in-an-if-statement-in-bash help?

Comment: This looks like you're changing the string *in your input*, not in your associative array... right? I don't see how the associative array is actually related to your question about updating values.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you could be right, maybe I'm coming at this wrong.  Is it possible to pipe and replace the string I care about as I'm passing it in?  i.e. `done < $FILEPATH | sed -i 's/invalid/UNKNOWN/g'` ?

Comment: `done < <(sed 's/invalid/UNKNOWN/g' <"$FILEPATH")`, but I still don't see why you're trying to change something in the *associative* array instead of the *indexed* array.

Comment: ie. `[[ ${array[7]} = invalid ]] && array[7]=UNKNOWN; [[ ${array[8]} = invalid ]] && array[8]=UNKNOWN` is AFAIK doing what you want, but by changing the *indexed* array `array`, instead of the *associative* array `hash`.

Comment: (that said, I'm not really convinced that you're getting value from using an indexed array here at all, instead of something like `while read -r _ _ _ _ _ _ fname lname _` or such, if in fact the fields you're reading are first and last name).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48480547/3776858

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that pops in my mind is creating a copy of the element with `UNKNOWN`

```
hash[UNKNOWN]=hash[invalid]
unset hash[invalid]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you could do:

```
hash[UNKNOWN]=${hash[invalid]}
unset hash[invalid]
```