# compare file names between directory and array

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a script for running two different commands according to the names of the files in a directory.

So far I created this small script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a sumas=("CPRAT1sfc.nc" "CPRAT2sfc.nc" "CPRATsfc.nc")

for files in *.nc; do
    if [ "$files"="${sumas[@]}" ]; then
        cdo daymean $files {$files}_d.nc
    else
        cdo daysum $files {$files}_d.nc
    fi
done
```

I'm trying to get all the files that end in `.nc`, then check if they are named different to the names in the `sumas` array.

For the files that are named the same, a command will run: `cdo daymean input output` and the output file will have the same name as the input but with a `_d.nc` at the end (still have to remove the .nc of the input so they won't end up as `.nc_d.nc`).

If their names are different to `sumas` then another command will run, with a similar syntax as the previous.

I though the script was ready but I'm getting this error: 
`scriptCDO.sh: 4: scriptCDO.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: The immediate problem is that you're trying to run a bash script with an interpreter for a different language, specifically `sh`. Use `bash` instead, or preferably, `./yourfile` to use the file specified in the shebang. However, there are several other problems. Use shellcheck and fixed those issues first, then update.

Comment: can you put `echo BASH_VERSION=$BASH_VERSION` inside this script, run it and show it's output?

Comment: @KamilCuk it shows BASH_VERSION=4.4.12(1)-release

Comment: Thanks @thatotherguy !. I'm kind of new on this... after your comment I was able to run it with ./scriptname but now I get that a binary operator is expected on the "if..." line. :/ I thought it was currently written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have enough information because $i is not set but your issue had to do with the comparison method mainly. Have a look at this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
BASE_DIR="/tmp/"  # change this to your base folder name
declare -a sumas=( "CPRAT1sfc.nc" "CPRAT2sfc.nc" "CPRATsfc.nc" )
i=1 # you need to set this to something

cd "${BASE_DIR}"
for each in * ; do
    if [[ "${sumas[@]}" =~ "${each}" ]] ;then
        echo "HERE -- cdo daymean $each {$i}_d.nc"
    else
        echo "NOT HERE -- cdo daysum $echo {$i}_d.nc"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your observation! I already update it but now I get that a binary operator is expected on the "if..." line

Comment: @Guillermo.D , sorry before I did not test code, the above code works for me on BASH4+.

Comment: Thanks! But one easy question... why is that in this case we need the [[ instead of a single [ ?

Comment: good question, there are many ways to test but the one we are using '=~' would read incorrectly with single quotes, I use phpStorm and with bash extension and it tells me there is a problem when I remove one of the [

Comment: have look at this post (and mine in this post) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277665/how-do-i-compare-two-string-variables-in-an-if-statement-in-bash/50572594#50572594