# Unexpected output for bash argument equality check

Tags: linux, bash, shell, equality

I have a basic string equality check in a Bash script, but the output is not as expected.

To reproduce, copy the code below into an executable file ***(called 'deploy' in my examples below)***.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1

if [[ "$1" -eq "--help" ]] || [[ "$1" -eq "-h" ]]; then
    echo "hello"
fi
```

---

If I run the script like so:

`./deploy -h`

The output is:

```
-h
hello
```

If I run the script like so:

`./deploy --help`

The output is:

```
-help
```

---

**Why does the conditional statement not resolve to true?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare strings in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2237080/608639), [How do I compare two string variables in an 'if' statement in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4277665/608639), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-eq` compares integers. Use `==` or `=` to compare strings.

```
if [[ "$1" == "--help" ]] || [[ "$1" == "-h" ]]; then
    echo "hello"
fi
```

You could omit the quotes. Variable expansions on the left-hand side of `==` are safe when using double brackets.

You can also use `||` inside the brackets. It's not possible to do that with single brackets, but double brackets are a syntactical feature with special parsing rules that allow it.

```
if [[ $1 == --help || $1 == -h ]]; then
    echo "hello"
fi
```

If it gets more complicated you might also consider a `case` block.

```
case $1 in
    -h|--help)
        echo "hello";;
esac
```

---

> If `-eq` is for numerical comparison, how come `./deploy -h` worked as expected?

Arithmetic evaluation normally prints an error message when given illegal expressions, but as it happens the two strings you're asking it to evaluate are syntactically valid.

- `-h` negates the value of the undefined variable `$h`. The result is 0.
- `--help` is decrements the undefined variable `$help`. The result is -1.

Try an invalid string and you'll get an error.

```
$ ./deploy 'foo bar'
bash: [[: foo bar: syntax error in expression (error token is "bar")
$ ./deploy @
bash: [[: @: syntax error in expression (error token is "@")
```

Comment: It's also tagged `bash`, has a `#!/bin/bash` shebang, and uses `[[`.