# BASH - getting invalid response when using until or while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, until-loop

I was able to create the if-elif-then-else code block on a separate script and validated working fine. However when I added the UNTIL or WHILE logic I'm getting the invalid response. I'm **NOT** expecting to get this response = **"invalid operation"** if I manually created the **VALIDATE.txt** file with either **"proceed"** or **"rollback"** inside the file. Please check my code below

**WHILE SCRIPT**

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/Users/lagot/Documents/BASH-TEST/VALIDATE.txt
ACTION=`cat /Users/lagot/Documents/BASH-TEST/VALIDATE.txt >>/dev/null 2>&1`
while [ ! -f "$FILE" ]
do
  echo "not exist"
  sleep 60
done

  if [ "${ACTION}" = "proceed" ];
    then
      echo "performing proceed"
      rm -rf $FILE
  elif [ "${ACTION}" = "rollback" ];
    then
      echo "performing rollback"
      rm -rf $FILE
  else
      echo "invalid operation"
      rm -rf $FILE
  fi
```

**UNTIL SCRIPT**

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/Users/lagot/Documents/BASH-TEST/VALIDATE.txt
ACTION=`cat /Users/lagot/Documents/BASH-TEST/VALIDATE.txt >>/dev/null 2>&1`
until [ -f "$FILE" ]
do
   echo "not exist"
   sleep 60
done
if [ "${ACTION}" = "proceed" ];
  then
    echo "performing proceed"
    rm -rf $FILE
elif [ "${ACTION}" = "rollback" ];
  then
    echo "performing rollback"
    rm -rf $FILE
else
    echo "invalid operation"
    rm -rf $FILE
fi
```

I created the VALIDATE.txt on a separate window and checked myself

```
lagot-pc:BASH-TEST lagot$ echo proceed >> VALIDATE.txt
lagot-pc:BASH-TEST lagot$ pwd
/Users/lagot/Documents/BASH-TEST
lagot-pc:BASH-TEST lagot$ cat /Users/lagot/Documents/BASH-TEST/VALIDATE.txt
proceed
```

I'm getting the invalid response **"invalid operation"** instead of **"performing proceed"** same also if I try to create the **VALIDATE.txt** and echo the **"rollback"** inside of the file

```
lagot-pc:BASH-TEST lagot$ ./while-script.sh
not exist
not exist
not exist
not exist
not exist
invalid operation
```

Comment: `elif [[ "${ACTION}"= "rollback" ]];` should be `elif [[ "${ACTION}" == "rollback" ]];` `=` means assignment and `==` means compare also need to put space between variable and operator

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277665/how-do-i-compare-two-string-variables-in-an-if-statement-in-bash

Comment: @DigvijayS That's incorrect. Within a `[[ ]]` conditional expression, `=` and `==` are equivalent. You're thinking of a `(( ))` arithmetic expression. And BTW, in a `[ ]` test expression, only `=` is standard for comparison (although some shells allow `==` as a synonym).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you. Then only issue is no white space between variable and operator

Comment: I just modified the bash script according to suggestion from Digvijay S and Gordon Davisson. I'm still getting the same response while testing it

Comment: In the `ACTION= ... >>/dev/null 2>&1` commands, the redirects will mean there's no output to capture and store in `ACTION`, so `ACTION` will never contain any of the strings you're checking for. Also, you read (/try to read) the file *before* waiting for it to exist, which makes no sense; I'm pretty sure you want that *after* the loop. Try putting `set -x` at the beginning of the script, so it prints what it's doing as it runs, and you can see more about what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Davisson, I already have the script working. I also added the fixes on the script above

Comment: @GordonDavisson : AFIK, not exactly correct: Inside a `[[ ... ]]`, `=` tests string equality, and `==` interprets the rhs as a glob-pattern.

Comment: @user1934428 Actually, in `[[ ]]`, both `=` and `==` will treat the RHS as a glob if it's not quoted. Try `[[ foo = *o* ]] && echo "Pattern matched"`. This applies in zsh and ksh93 as well as in bash.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you for pointing this out. It is indeed also documented well in the man page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is now fixed, I also added the new format of UNTIL and WHILE scripts below**

**FIX IN WHILE SCRIPT**

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/Users/lagot/Documents/BASH-TEST/VALIDATE.txt

while [ ! -f "$FILE" ]
do
  echo "not exist"
  sleep 60
done

  if [ `cat "$FILE"` = "proceed" ];
    then
      echo "performing proceed"
      rm -rf $FILE
  elif [ `cat "$FILE"` = "rollback" ];
    then
      echo "performing rollback"
      rm -rf $FILE
  else
      echo "invalid operation"
      rm -rf $FILE
  fi
```

**FIX IN UNTIL SCRIPT**

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/Users/lagot/Documents/BASH-TEST/VALIDATE.txt

until [ -f "$FILE" ]
do
   echo "not exist"
   sleep 60
done
if [ `cat $FILE` = "proceed" ];
  then
    echo "performing proceed"
    rm -rf $FILE
elif [ `cat $FILE` = "rollback" ];
  then
    echo "performing rollback"
    rm -rf $FILE
else
    echo "invalid operation"
    rm -rf $FILE
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the original code [assigns `$ACTION` incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056553/bash-getting-invalid-response-when-using-until-or-while-loop#comment109757695_62056553), and worse, it wrongly attempts the assignment before making sure `$FILE` exists.  So change these lines:

```
FILE=/Users/lagot/Documents/BASH-TEST/VALIDATE.txt
ACTION=`cat /Users/lagot/Documents/BASH-TEST/VALIDATE.txt >>/dev/null 2>&1`
until [ -f "$FILE" ]
do
   echo "not exist"
   sleep 60
done
```

To:

```
FILE=/Users/lagot/Documents/BASH-TEST/VALIDATE.txt
until [ -f "$FILE" ]
do
   echo "not exist"
   sleep 60
done
ACTION=$(<$FILE)
```

Or, (since `$(<$FILE)` returns an error code), with one line less:

```
FILE=/Users/lagot/Documents/BASH-TEST/VALIDATE.txt
until { ACTION=$(<$FILE); } 2> /dev/null
do
   echo "not exist"
   sleep 60
done
```

After that, the rest of the original code that tests `${ACTION}` should work.

---

Don't confuse the **`>>`** redirect (append to existing file, or create if file doesn't exist) with *`>`* (overwrite file, or create if file doesn't exist).  So code like this `echo proceed >> VALIDATE.txt` should be `echo proceed > VALIDATE.txt`, otherwise if *VALIDATE.txt* already exists and contains *"rollback"* the result will be a two line *VALIDATE.txt* file:

```
rollback
proceed
```