# Searching for a substring in a bash script will not work

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have been writing a bash script to call in my .bashrc file to print the results of whatis for a random command in my /usr/bin folder and wanted to exclude commands that returned "nothing appropriate" in the result and even if I use grep, wc, expr, ==, nothing seems to work. I have pretty much used every example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467735/how-to-find-substring-inside-a-string-or-how-to-grep-a-variable), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash) with no progress. This is what I have so far but failes to do what I want when it finds somthing that contains "nothing appropriate." If anyone could figure out how to get it to work or what a good solution would be in this situation I would be greatfull.

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Did you know that:";
while :
do
  RESULT=$(whatis $(ls /usr/bin | shuf -n 1))
  if [[ $RESULT != *"nothing appropriate"* ]]
  then
    echo $RESULT
    break
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whatis` prints the `nothing appropriate` message on the standard error stream. This stream is not caught by the `$( )`. This is the reason of your issue.

This is a way to fix it:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Did you know that:";
while :
do
  RESULT=$(whatis $(ls /usr/bin | shuf -n 1) 2>&1 | cat - )
  if [[ $RESULT != *"nothing appropriate"* ]]
  then
    echo $RESULT
    break
  fi
done
```

The `2>&1 | cat -` addition does the trick

Comment: What's the `cat -` for?

Comment: O man, that never even crossed my mind. Thanks for figuring out what the problem was. It probably will but i hope that that doesn't get me again or at least i realize sooner.