# How to check if a file contains a specific string using Bash

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I want to check if a file contains a specific string or not in bash. I used this script, but it doesn't work:

```
 if [[ 'grep 'SomeString' $File' ]];then
   # Some Actions
 fi
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749330/how-to-test-if-string-exists-in-file-with-bash-shell

Comment: Here's how to grep the output of a `command`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375722/how-do-i-test-in-one-line-if-command-output-contains-a-certain-string

Answer (score 730, accepted):

```
if grep -q SomeString "$File"; then
  Some Actions # SomeString was found
fi
```

You don't need `[[ ]]` here. Just run the command directly. Add `-q` option when you don't need the string displayed when it was found.

The `grep` command returns 0 or 1 in the exit code depending on
the result of search. 0 if something was found; 1 otherwise.

```
$ echo hello | grep hi ; echo $?
1
$ echo hello | grep he ; echo $?
hello
0
$ echo hello | grep -q he ; echo $?
0
```

You can specify commands as an condition of `if`. If the command returns 0 in its exitcode that means that the condition is true; otherwise false.

```
$ if /bin/true; then echo that is true; fi
that is true
$ if /bin/false; then echo that is true; fi
$
```

As you can see you run here the programs directly. No additional `[]` or `[[]]`.

Comment: More information about `grep` and available options in asnwer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4749368/1702557

Comment: might want to consider `-Fxq` parameters as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/4749368/544721

Comment: consider using `-m 1` in order to improve scanning performance. Returns on the first occurrence.

Comment: if `SomeString` contains regex special characters (like `.`) you might get unexpected results. It's safer to always use `fgrep` (or `grep -F`) (unless you really need a regex, in which case `egrep` (or `grep -E`) is probably the best choice)

Comment: The example `if` example is incorrect, as it only checks if the exit code was non-0. If any error happens, like the file can't be read, the exit code is also non-0. So you have to do something like `ec=$?`, and check if it's `0` (found), then if it's `1` (not found), and then if it's something else (fail).

Comment: `if ! grep -q SomeString ...` If you want to negate, use a `!` and a space.

Comment: What if I'm using ```set -e```?

Comment: @PaulKnopf: `set -e` does not interfere with `if`

Comment: What is the result of `echo hello | grep hi` or `echo hello | grep he`, question for bash starters like me;) This does not work: `if grep -q SomeString "$File"; then`, but this `if echo $file | grep -q SomeString ; then..` on a ..... guess what ... mac

Comment: If grep returns 0 on a successful match, why is the condition getting executed? Shouldn't the if condition be false?

Comment: @Loner: 0 exit code means true, or I didn't get your question?

Answer (score 111):

In case if you want to check whether file does **not** contain a specific string, you can do it as follows.

```
if ! grep -q SomeString "$File"; then
  Some Actions # SomeString was not found
fi
```

Comment: Suppose you have several stings in an "input file" that you want to test. Can you combine your solution with `cat` (and `xargs`)? Or do you need a for loop?

Comment: Is this possible to compare lines from a variable to lines from a text file? Is there a way to set multiple lines to compare instead of `SomeString` ?

Comment: `grep -v` also negates the condition

Answer (score 49):

In addition to other answers, which told you how to do what you wanted, I try to explain what was wrong (which is what you wanted.

In Bash, `if` is to be followed with a command. If the exit code of this command is equal to 0, then the `then` part is executed, else the `else` part if any is executed.

You can do that with any command as explained in other answers: `if /bin/true; then ...; fi`

`[[` is an internal bash command dedicated to some tests, like file existence, variable comparisons. Similarly `[` is an external command (it is located typically in `/usr/bin/[`) that performs roughly the same tests but needs `]` as a final argument, which is why `]` must be padded with a space on the left, which is not the case with `]]`.

Here you needn't `[[` nor `[`.

Another thing is the way you quote things. In bash, there is only one case where pairs of quotes do nest, it is `"$(command "argument")"`. But in `'grep 'SomeString' $File'` you have only one word, because `'grep '` is a quoted unit, which is concatenated with `SomeString` and then again concatenated with `' $File'`. The variable `$File` is not even replaced with its value because of the use of single quotes. The proper way to do that is `grep 'SomeString' "$File"`.

Answer (score 24):

Shortest (correct) version:

```
grep -q "something" file; [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

can be also written as

```
grep -q "something" file; test $? -eq 0 && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

but you dont need to explicitly test it in this case, so the same with:

```
grep -q "something" file && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

Comment: `if grep -q something file; then echo yes; else echo no; fi`. No reason to mess with `$?` at all.

Answer (score 12):

```
##To check for a particular  string in a file

cd PATH_TO_YOUR_DIRECTORY #Changing directory to your working directory
File=YOUR_FILENAME  
if grep -q STRING_YOU_ARE_CHECKING_FOR "$File"; ##note the space after the string you are searching for
then
echo "Hooray!!It's available"
else
echo "Oops!!Not available"
fi
```

Comment: Changing directory is usually not a good idea (and is completely unnecessary here, just qualify the filename with the target directory). And then what you have is exactly the same thing as the accepted answer, only with less details.

Answer (score 11):

```
if grep -q [string] [filename]
then
    [whatever action]
fi
```

***Example***

```
if grep -q 'my cat is in a tree' /tmp/cat.txt
then
    mkdir cat
fi
```

Answer (score 11):

```
grep -q [PATTERN] [FILE] && echo $?
```

The exit status is `0` (true) if the pattern was found; otherwise blankstring.

Answer (score 8):

In case you want to checkif the string matches the whole line and if it  is a fixed string, You can do it this way

```
grep -Fxq [String] [filePath]
```

example

```
 searchString="Hello World"
 file="./test.log"
 if grep -Fxq "$searchString" $file
    then
            echo "String found in $file"
    else
            echo "String not found in $file"
 fi
```

From the man file:

```
-F, --fixed-strings

          Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of 

which is to be matched.
          (-F is specified by POSIX.)
-x, --line-regexp
          Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.  (-x is specified by 

POSIX.)
-q, --quiet, --silent
          Quiet; do not write anything to standard output.  Exit immediately with zero 

status  if  any  match  is
          found,  even  if  an error was detected.  Also see the -s or --no-messages 

option.  (-q is specified by
          POSIX.)
```

Comment: It does not work.  For instance , if i am looking for the line 'hello' and there is one line that says 'hello world' , the answer should be  'hello not found in file' as hello DOES NOT EQUAL THE ENTIRE LINE .

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if [[ $(grep "SomeString" $File) ]] ; then
   echo "Found"
else
   echo "Not Found"
fi
```

Comment: I'm hesitantly abstaining from downvoting this, but Stack Overflow should not perpetuate this sort of pretzel logic.  `grep` returns an exit status for a very good reason; capturing output into a string is potentially going to store a large amount of text in a buffer just so you can say it's non-empty.

Comment: @tripleee this kind of answer is literally what downvotes are designed for.

Answer (score -1):

I done this, seems to work fine

```
if grep $SearchTerm $FileToSearch; then
   echo "$SearchTerm found OK"
else
   echo "$SearchTerm not found"
fi
```

Comment: [The quoting is broken](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable), and you probably want to avoid seeing the output from `grep`.

Answer (score -3):

```
grep -q "something" file
[[ !? -eq 0 ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

Comment: You have a typo - !? is supposed to be $?

Comment: ...not only is it intended to be `$?`, but there's no need for it at all -- you could just do `if grep -q ...`

Comment: Moreover, `foo && truthy_action || falsey_action` isn't a real ternary operator -- if `truthy_action` fails, then `falsey_action` gets run _in addition_.

Comment: More generally, the *purpose* of `if` is to run a command and check its exit code. You should very rarely need to examine `$?` explicitly.