# How do I test (in one line) if command output contains a certain string?

Tags: bash

In one line of bash, how do I return an exit status of 0 when the output of `/usr/local/bin/monit --version` doesn't contain exactly `5.5` and an exit status of 1 when it does?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```
! /usr/local/bin/monit --version | grep -q 5.5
```

(`grep` returns an exit-status of 0 if it finds a match, and 1 otherwise. The `-q` option, "quiet", tells it not to print any match it finds; in other words, it tells `grep` that the only thing you want is its return-value. The `!` at the beginning inverts the exit-status of the whole pipeline.)

**Edited to add:** Alternatively, if you want to do this in "pure Bash" (rather than calling `grep`), you can write:

```
[[ $(/usr/local/bin/monit --version) != *5.5* ]]
```

(`[[...]]` is explained in [§3.2.4.2 "Conditional Constructs" of the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs). `*5.5*` is just like in fileglobs: zero or more characters, plus `5.5`, plus zero or more characters.)

Comment: Is there any to echo out the value of `/usr/local/bin/monit --version` when it fails as well?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter: Please clarify -- what do you mean by "when it fails"? (Which direction is "failure"?)

Comment: @ruakh When the exit code is 1, can it display the `monit --version` value while still exiting with a status of 1?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter: The exit code of `grep`, or the exit code of the whole command? (Due to the `!`, those are the opposite of each other.)

Comment: @JoshuaPinter: Put another way: are you saying that you want to display what `/usr/local/bin/monit --version` printed when it *does* print something containing `5.5`, or when it *doesn't*?

Comment: You're right, it's confusing because of the `!`. Here's what I ended up using, for others that might be looking at this: `monit --version | grep 5.5 || (c=$?; echo $(monit --version); (exit $c))`

Comment: @JoshuaPinter: That seems equivalent to `monit --version; monit --version | grep -q 5.5`; but I'm guessing you meant to use `grep -q` instead of bare `grep`? In that case you could simplify slightly to `monit --version | grep -q 5.5 || (monit --version; false)`. And -- does `monit --version` ever print multiple lines? If not, then you can simplify down to just `! monit --version | grep -v 5.5`.

Comment: @ruakh Genius. Of course, just print the monit version first and then run the grep to get the exit code. I'll give that a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

```
[ $(/usr/local/bin/monit --version) == "5.5" ]
```

eg-1: check for success

```
[ $(/usr/local/bin/monit --version) == "5.5" ] && echo "OK"
```

eg-2: check for failure

```
[ $(/usr/local/bin/monit --version) == "5.5" ] || echo "NOT OK"
```

or, to just check if the output contains `5.5`:

```
[[ $(/usr/local/bin/monit --version) =~ "5.5" ]] || echo "NOT OK"
```

Comment: "5.5" will be part of a larger amount output.

Comment: @perreal - You can't quote regex in bash, it makes it a literal string rather than a regex. (quoting works in some older versions of bash, but was fixed as a bug).

Comment: @jordanm, that's not correct. If you don't quote 5.5 it will also match 5a5. The quotes make the dot a string.

Comment: @perreal I just tested it. `[[ "5a5" =~ "5.5" ]] && echo yes` prints nothing but `[[ "5a5" =~ 5.5 ]] && echo yes` print yes. The quoted version works in zsh, but not in bash.

Answer (score 7):

Test the return value of grep:

```
sudo service xyz status | grep 'not' &> /dev/null
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
   echo "whateveryouwant"
fi
```

I would recommend cron, it works fine with SALT stack