# How to check if string is part of command "python --version" in bash?

Tags: bash

In bash, I wish to check whether Python 2.7 is installed. While searching SO I found this: [How do I test (in one line) if command output contains a certain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375722/how-do-i-test-in-one-line-if-command-output-contains-a-certain-string)

In bash, I have this:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.11
```

And so I tried this:

```
[[ $(python --version) =~ "2.7" ]] || echo "I don't have 2.7"
Python 2.7.11
I don't have 2.7
```

...which I found strange, as I expected that to work.

I also tried this:

```
if [[ $(python --version) =~ *2.7* ]]
    then
        echo "I have 2.7"
    else
        echo "I don't have 2.7"
fi
```

...which resulted in:

```
Python 2.7.11
I don't have 2.7
```

Hm!
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python --version` command outputs to `stderr`.

You can redirect `stderr` to `stdout` prior to test:

```
if [[ $(python --version 2>&1) =~ 2\.7 ]]
    then
        echo "I have 2.7"
    else
        echo "I don't have 2.7"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way. You can first check if `python` is installed from the `which` command and then capture the output of `python --version`

```
if which python > /dev/null 2>&1;
then
    if [[ $(python --version 2>&1) == *2\.7\.11 ]]; then
       echo "Python version 2.7.11 is installed."
    fi 
else
    echo "No Python executable is found."
fi
```