# Script for adding a disk to fstab if not existing

Tags: bash, path, grep

First of all, I have read many posts (see at bottom) with if-clauses to search in a file for a specific string and followed these posts 1to1, however I don't manage to get my script to work. I want to make an entry in `/etc/fstab` if it doesn't exist yet:

```
#!/bin/bash
fstab=/etc/fstab

if grep -q "poky-disc" "$fstab"
then
    echo "#poky-disc" >> /etc/fstab
    echo "/dev/sdb1 /media/poky ext4 defaults 0 2" >> /etc/fstab
else
    echo "Entry in fstab exists."
fi
```

Thanks for your help in advance. These are the similar posts, which didnt help me further:

- [How to test if string exists in file with Bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4749330/5316879)
- [How to check if a file contains a specific string using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11287861/5316879)

Comment: It looks like you need to reverse the `then..else` contents

Comment: I tried it with inversion, too. `grep -q "poky-disc" "$fstab"`and `grep "poky-disc" "$fstab"`

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Oh damn through your impact I found out that `-q` isn't the option for Inversion, but just suspending the output, a short `man grep` helped me. And I was reading topics about paths and grep...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a simple and hopefully idiomatic solution.

```sh
grep -q 'init-poky' /etc/fstab || 
printf '# init-poky\n/dev/sdb1    /media/poky    ext4    defaults    0    2\n' >> /etc/fstab
```

If the exit status from `grep -q` is `false`, execute the `printf`.  The `||` shorthand can be spelled out as

```sh
if grep -q 'ínit-poky' /etc/fstab; then
    : nothing
else
    printf ...
fi
```

Many beginners do not realize that the argument to `if` is a command whose exit status determines whether the `then` branch or the `else` branch will be taken.

Answer (score 7):

Elegant and short way:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! grep -q 'init-poky' /etc/fstab ; then
    echo '# init-poky' >> /etc/fstab
    echo '/dev/sdb1    /media/poky    ext4    defaults    0    2' >> /etc/fstab
fi
```

It uses native Bash command exit code ($?=0 for success and >0 for error code) and if grep produces error, means NOT FOUND, it does inverse (!) of result, and adds fstab entry.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I managed to edit it with this command:

```
sudo su -c "echo '#test' >> /etc/fstab"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
fstab=/etc/fstab

if [[ $(grep -q "poky-disc" "$fstab") ]]
# forgiving me for being a bit of over-rigorous, you might want to change this matching word, as below, 'poky-disc' merely a comment, not exactly a config line, so
then
    echo "#poky-disc" >> /etc/fstab
    echo "/dev/sdb1 /media/poky ext4 defaults 0 2" >> /etc/fstab
else
    echo "Entry in fstab exists."
fi
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you also explain the usage of the 2nd line "fstab=/etc/fstab" here?

Comment: Creating an `fstab` variable doesn't make much sense as it is written. First of all it's always going to be `/etc/fstab`, but even if it were to change it wouldn't be helpful as you're not consistent in using the variable.

Comment: The command substitution is completely wrong here. You are checking if `grep -q` outputs a non-empty string, which of course it will never do.  You simply want `if ! grep -q "poky-disc" "$fstab"; then`

Comment: FWIW, this error is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371221/bash-if-statement-too-many-arguments