# Check all files in directory whether they contain specific string two or more times

Tags: bash, grep

I would like to check all files in a directory whether they can contain two or more occurrences of a string.

Checking for a single "[occurrence of a specific string using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287861/how-to-check-if-a-file-contains-a-specific-string-using-bash/11287896)" seems easy:

```
if grep -q "LineString" "$File"; then
  Some Actions # SomeString was found
fi
```

But how to count to two?

Comment: Use the `-c` switch. That will return the count of matching lines as grep's output

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the file and the string to be searched

Comment: The answer below should work for your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(( ))` for the numeric comparison:

```
if (( $(grep -c -- "LineString" "$file") >= 2 )); then
  # your logic
fi
```

To loop through all files:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob # make glob expand to nothing if there are no matching files
for file in *; do
    [[ -f $file ]] || continue
    if (( $(grep -c -- "LineString" "$file") >= 2 )); then
      # your logic
    fi
done
```

If you are dealing with very huge files and your `grep` supports the `-m` option, then you can use `grep -cm 2` to optimize the reads:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *; do
    [[ -f $file ]] || continue
    if (( $(grep -cm 2 -- "LineString" "$file") >= 2 )); then
      # your logic
    fi
done
```

Comment: Note that `-c` is a standard option for `grep`, but `-m` is not. (Also, it may depend on the implementation , but `-m` and `-c` can be combined to avoid the need to use `wc -l`.)

Comment: From the 2nd answer I'm getting an "unexpected fi" error. Shouldn't I close the for() loop with an done?

for file in *; do
 [[ -f $file ]] || continue
 filename="${file##*/}"
 echo $filename
 if (( $(grep -c -- "LineString" "$file") >= 2 )); then
  mv $file "$filename.bak"
  echo "select ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(geometry)) from $file";
  ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -explodecollections -dialect sqlite -sql \
  "select ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(geometry)) from $file" "$filename.geojson" "$filename.bak"
 fi
done

Comment: Corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks @chepner.  Updated the answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: Since merging "MultiLineStrings" doesn't work – can I exclude them from the search? (Sorry, that's a little bit funny!)

Comment: That seems like a different requirement.  Please update your question appropriately or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if [ `grep "LineString" $file | wc -l` -gt 1 ]; then 
    echo "done found";
    ' do something
fi;
```