# How to fail a Github Actions step when it succeeds, but it has 'error' in the logs

Tags: github, github-actions, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have a github actions job that has a step like this

```
      - name: Deploy to EKS
        uses: tensor-hq/eksctl-helm-action@main
        with:
          eks_cluster: ${{ env.CLUSTER_NAME }}
          command: |-
             helm upgrade --install test a-super-chart -n test-ns --set somevalue=someValue
```

When something is wonky with the executed helm command...say an empty value or anything that makes Helm install/upgrade to fail, the step shows as successful but there is an error in the logs.

For example, like this.

```
Error: failed to parse .github/values_for_stg_alb_ingress.yaml: 
error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}
{".Values.ingress.ingressClassName | default \"alb\"":interface {}(nil)}
```

Is there a way to make the workflow fail in such occasions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could always put the command line output inside a txt file (using `| true > output.txt` at the end of the command line), and then check if the file.txt contains the string "Error" using `grep` [(reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287861/how-to-check-if-a-file-contains-a-specific-string-using-bash). Then, if the file contains the string, run `exit 1` to fail the step (and consequently, the job).

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was thinking as a fallback solution...but I was wondering if there is a more 'github native' solution.

Comment: As the command doesn't return an exit code 1, I don't think there is any alternative solution :/

Comment: I would consider this a bug in the action, perhaps open an issue there.