# How do I test for a file pattern stored in a variable?

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a filename in a variable.

```
FILENAME_VAR = "1000-Feature.mp4"
```

What is the bash command I can use to test that the filename in the variable `$FILENAME_VAR` contains the word `Feature`?

Comment: BTW you can't have spaces around the `=` in a shell assignment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749330/how-to-test-if-string-exists-in-file-with-bash-shell

Comment: The top 2 voted answers in [String contains in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash) should be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it

```sh
if [[ $FILENAME_VAR =~ Feature ]]
then
  echo good
else
  echo bad
fi
```

Comment: Steven, I tried your way, but it doesn't seem to work. What I'm testing is to see if the word "Feature" exists in the variable, not in the actual file.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ [[ $FILENAME_VAR = *Feature* ]] ; echo $?
0
$ [[ $FILENAME_VAR = *Feature2* ]] ; echo $?
1
```