# Bash regex =~ operator

Tags: bash, shell, unix

What is the operator `=~` called? Is it only used to compare the right side against the left side?

Why are double square brackets required when running a test?

ie. `[[ $phrase =~ $keyword ]]`

Thank you

Answer (score 111, accepted):

1. > What is the operator `=~` called?

   I'm not sure it has a name.  The [bash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) just calls it the `=~` operator.
2. > Is it only used to compare the right side against the left side?

   The right side is considered an extended regular expression.  If the left side matches, the operator returns `0`, and `1` otherwise.
3. > Why are double square brackets required when running a test?

   Because `=~` is an operator of the `[[ expression ]]` compound command.

Comment: If the left side matches, the operator returns 0 or 1 as you say, but it also sets the `BASH_REMATCH` array, which bears mentioning. Also, `[[` is not a command – It's a keyword.

Comment: Yup - all further information available at the doc link above.

Comment: bash is weird. `type [[` says that `[[` is a shell keyword, but the manpage does refer to `[[` as a *conditional command* at least once. Meh.

Comment: `[[` is a shell keyword which introduces a compound command `[[ ... ]]`, just like `if` is a shell keyword that introduces the `if..then..fi` compound command.

Comment: perhaps it is called the Equal Tilde operator

Comment: How can you use matching operator with logical operator? e.g. "if [ [[ $a =~ 'ab' ]] -o [[ $b =~ 'cd' ]] ]; then ... " is working ?

Comment: @JoonhoPark - I'd recommend against mixing & matching `[` and `[[` like that. Why not just `if [[ $a =~ 'ab' || $b =~ 'cd' ]]`?

Comment: +1 In addition to a great answer, specifying a link to bash documentation encourages readers to dig in deeper. Thanks!

Answer (score 56):

The `=~` operator is a regular expression match operator. This operator is inspired by Perl's use of the same operator for regular expression matching.

The `[[ ]]` is treated specially by bash; consider that an augmented version of `[ ]` construct:

- `[ ]` is actually a shell built-in command, which, can actually be implemented as an external command. Look at your /usr/bin, there is most likely a program called "[" there! Strictly speaking, `[ ]` is not part of bash syntax.
- `[[ ]]` is a shell keyword, which means it is part of shell syntax. Inside this construct, some reserved characters change meaning. For example, `( )` means parenthesis like other programming language (not launching a subshell to execute what's inside the parentheses). Another example is that `<` and `>` means less than and greater than, not shell redirection. This allow more "natural" appearance of logical expressions, but it can be confusing for novice bash programmers.

Wirawan

Comment: Thanks for the easy and useful explanation of the difference between `[[ ]]` and `[ ]`... It cleared my mind

Comment: Though this is focusing on only a part of the question, it is helpful.

Comment: @LukeSavefrogs what did you understand from this? Can you help me to understand this?

Comment: @SD. `[` and `[[` are two different commands. Sometimes they are interchangeable but as of now it is *always* better to use the latter, which is more secure

Answer (score 7):

The `=~`operator is the pattern match operator. It did not exist in the original Bourne shell, when `test`, or internally `[ ]`, was used for conditionals.

The `let` command, or `[[ ]]` internally, has more functionality than `test`, including pattern matching capabilities. This is why you have to use `[[ ]]`, instead of `[ ]`, when using `=~`.