# How to use the =~ operand?

Tags: bash, shell, unary-operator, operands

I've bumped into a Nagios check script which has been written by someone who already left my company and there's an operator there which I can't understand it's use.
This is the relevant part from the shell script:

```
if [[ "$URL" =~ $ACTIVE ]] &&  [[ "$URL2" =~ $ACTIVE2 ]]; then
        echo "OK: $HOST is ACTIVE in the Load Balancer"
        exit 0
```

My question is:

What is this `=~`?

I've checked about it in the internet and found that it's a bitwise which "Flips the bits in the operand", but I don't understand where and how to use it, can you please elaborate?

Edit #1:
This is the full script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

#Purpose: Checks if proxy is active in the LB
#Date: May 09, 2011

#Variables
HOST=$1
URL=`wget --timeout=60 -w 3 -qO- http://$HOST:8080/proxy/keepalive?file=/workspace/temp/1`
URL2=`wget --timeout=60 -w 3 -qO- http://$HOST:8080/proxy/keepalive?file=/workspace/temp/1.txt`
ACTIVE="1"
ACTIVE2="ppp"
LOG="/tmp/PROXY-LB.log"


#Begin Code

if [ -z $HOST ]; then
        echo "You must specify IPADDRESS (e.g. 68.67.174.34)"
        exit 3
fi

if [[ "$URL" =~ $ACTIVE ]] &&  [[ "$URL2" =~ $ACTIVE2 ]]; then
        echo "OK: $HOST is ACTIVE in the Load Balancer"
        exit 0

else
        echo "*** Problem: $HOST is out from the Load Balancer" 
        echo "`date`: *** HOST $HOST is out from the Load Balancer" >> $LOG 2>&1
        exit 2

fi

#END
```

My question is, couldn't the coder use this (without the `~`) instead?

```
if [[ "$URL" = $ACTIVE ]] &&  [[ "$URL2" = $ACTIVE2 ]]; then
```

Edit #2:
Here are some examples I tried:

```
$ d="hello"
$ [[ "$d" =~ *ll* ]] && echo "yes"
$ [[ "$d" =~ he* ]] && echo "yes"
yes
$ [[ "$d" =~ *lo ]] && echo "yes"
$
```

Edit #3:
Okay, I've done some more tests and I believe I understand it now:

```
$ [[ "$d" =~ he* ]] && echo "yes"
yes
$ [[ "$d" =~ *lo ]] && echo "yes"
$ [[ "$d" =~ h* ]] && echo "yes"
yes
$ [[ "$d" =~ lo$ ]] && echo "yes"
yes
$ [[ "$d" =~ ^he ]] && echo "yes"
yes
$ [[ "$d" =~ [a-z]ll[a-z] ]] && echo "yes"
yes
$
```

Thank you all for your help and information!

Comment: Maybe this is your solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441521/bash-regex-operator

Comment: I'm just having a hard time to understand why it was used specifically in this script... and thanks, the information in this topic is also interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used to perform comparisons in strings.

```
if [[ "$URL" =~ $ACTIVE ]] &&  [[ "$URL2" =~ $ACTIVE2 ]]; then
```

Checks if `$URL` contains the content of the variable `$ACTIVE` and if `$URL2` contains the content of the variable `$ACTIVE2`.

See a test:

```
$ d="hello"
$ [[ "$d" =~ he* ]] && echo "yes"
yes
$ [[ "$d" =~ *ba* ]] && echo "yes"
$
$ [[ $d =~ .*ll.* ]] && echo "yes"
yes
```

In the last one you have to indicate the regex properly. It is equivalent to using `==` and just `*ll*`.

```
$ [[ $d == *ll* ]] && echo "yes"
yes
```

From `man bash` -> [3.2.4.2 Conditional Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> An additional binary operator, =~, is available, with the same
>   precedence as == and !=.   When  it  is  used,  the string  to  the 
>   right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and
>   matched accordingly (as in regex(3)).  The return value is 0 if the
>   string matches the pattern, and 1 otherwise.  If the  regular 
>   expression is  syntactically  incorrect,  the conditional expression's
>   return value is 2.

Comment: See my update for your edit#2. Will investigate edit#1 later.