# Bash: [[ ]] vs (( )) in =~ expression for "if then" script. Also meaning of =~ ^

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement, arithmetic-expressions

In [bash man](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs), the =~ operator is listed under [[ *expression* ]], and for expressions I should use closed brackets. This is also an accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19441575/6076137):

> (Double square brackets are required) "because `=~` is an operator of the `[[ expression ]]` compound command."

However, my script line with `=~` fails with closed brackets yet functions with open brackets. I would like to know what Bash is doing in both the open and closed bracket cases so that I might understand better how they function.

---

#### context

I would like to transfer files from `$R/x/` into `ppc/`, where `$R` is a number referring to 30 directories, their labels ranging from 2.0 to 5.0 in increments of 0.1

`x/` is a generic subdirectory label within $R.

Every 5th directory, ie: (2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0) I need to attach a condition for the script to pull only specific files from `x/` and leave the rest behind. These files all begin with 105 and are pulled with `$R/x/105*`.

My script works as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

for (( i=0;i<=30; i++ )) ;

do

R=$(echo "scale=2;2.0+0.1*$i" |bc -l)
#$R specifies a number corresponding to the directory I need

if (( $R =~ ^(2.0|2.5|3.0|3.5|4.0|4.5|5.0)$ )) ;
#This line is important. My question relates solely to this line.

then

cp -r $R/ ppc/

else

mkdir ppc/$R/ &&
mkdir ppc/$R/x &&

cp -r $R/x/105* ppc/$R/x
fi

done
```

So this works out fine. I just get a list of errors upon running the script for every value of `$R` from 2.0 to 5.0, ex for $R = 4.6:

```
./Script.in: line 11: ((: 4.6 =~ ^(2.0|2.5|3.0|3.5|4.0|4.5|5.0)$ : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".6 =~ ^(2.0|2.5|3.0|3.5|4.0|4.5|5.0)$ ")
```

but the end output result in /ppc is exactly what I wanted. I transfered all the 30 directories from $R = 2.0 to $R = 5.0, and every fifth directory I selectively pulled specific files.

---

However, if I change my "if" condition to:

```
if [[ $R =~ ^(2.0|2.5|3.0|3.5|4.0|4.5|5.0)$ ]] ;
   ^^                                       ^^
```

ie. closed brackets, I get zero error messages; however without the arithmetic my output goes to shit. The output is as if my script were written with no if/then condition at all:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

for (( i=0;i<=30; i++ )) ;

do

R=$(echo "scale=2;2.0+0.1*$i" |bc -l)

cp -r $R/ ppc/

done

rm -r ppc/2.0/
```

so just straight copying with no conditions, only somehow I also have no 2.0 directory in `ppc/`, so the first $R fails to compute entirely.

---

#### Questions

- Why does bash treat the "if" condition as arithmetic instead of say, text strings? Will I always need open parentheses any time I have a number involved even if the manual labels it as a closed bracket expression?
- How is the "if" condition being interpreted by Bash with closed brackets? I am wondering how I got the result I did. I don't believe it entirely ignored the if condition, because the 2.0 directory did not print.
- Why do I get those errors with the open brackets? Can I fix that?
- Side question: the `^` in

  =~ **^**(

  means "not equal to," is that correct? As in it functions like "!=~" if that operator existed? I could not find its meaning in the manual. I copied that command from online in stack. My understanding is that if I leave `^` out, the script will look for = rather than !=

Thank you!

Comment: Regex evaluation using `=~` is only supported in `[[ ... ]]` and even though your regex is not entirely correct it should work for given range of `i` in `for` loop.

Comment: I suggest spending some time reading the man page. `(( ... ))` is a command for arithmetic expressions only. The `^` following `=~` is just the start-of-string anchor in the regular expression.

Comment: The token following an `if` is a *command* and that equates to True if the command is successful (i.e. if it has a return value of zero).  The brackets, `[[`, `((`, or `[` are all different commands.   `[[` is mostly used for text pattern matching and `((` is used for arithmetics.  `[` is the old Bourne shell `test` command.

Comment: Please only ask one thing at a time. Please read the [help] pages about how to ask questions here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. @anubhava I understand =~ is for [[ ... ]]. That is why I am curious why (( ... )) works. &chepner Thank you for the clarification on ^; I thought it might be that. As mentioned, I know (( ... )) is for arithmetic expressions *only*. Why does it work for an operator the manual indicates is strictly [[ ... ]]? &cdarke My script is functioning as !~ as best I can understand? That confused me because the manual indicates =~ is for matching expressions, not the opposite. Do you know why it is working as !~ ?

Comment: @AdrianHHH Sorry for asking multiple questions. Is it then preferable I copy+paste repost this 4 times? I'm okay with either protocol.

Comment: @cdarke `!~` is not in bash..