# Why does this shell script exit without reading `case`?

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a `bash` shell script for practice, but can't seem to fix its behavior. The script copies an array of files and directories into a given backup directory, *$path*, and compresses it to a *.tar.gz* file.

The iteration I'm working on should check if said *.tar.gz* file already exists using the naming pattern for backup directory (*$date_value.tar.gz*), and has specific cases depending on the answer. The script is expected to be ran from main project directory for now.

The following code is the part that goes wrong.

```
if [ -f "$path/$date_value.tar.gz" ] ; then

  echo "A $date_value.tar.gz directory already exists."

  read -p "Do you wish to update directory ? (Y/N)"

  echo # Moves to new line; for user experience purpose only

  case $REPLY in

        # Case when user wrote "Y" or "y" as in Yes
        " [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]] " )

            # Extract archive
            tar xf "$path/$date_value.tar.gz"

            # Synchronise directories
            rsync --update -raz --progress \ 
                  --include="$current_path${files_array[@]}" "$path/$date_value" \
                  --exclude="*"

   exit 0;
;;

        # Case when user wrote anything else
        " [[ $REPLY =~ ^[*]$ ]] " )

            echo "Script didn't make any change and stopped itself."

    exit 1;
esac

# Else if backup directory doesn't exist yet
else

    # Make a directory using the date
    mkdir "$path/$date_value"

    # Loops over the whole array and copies files/directories
    # recursively to given directory with current rights
    for i in ${files_array[@]}; do
            cp -ar ${i} /home/robin/backup/by_date/"$date_value"/
    done

    # Goes to backup directory
    cd "$path"

    # Compress backup directory into tarball AND(=&&) removes it if successfull
    tar cfM "$date_value.tar.gz" "$date_value" && rm -Rf "$date_value"

fi
```

When run in `bash -x` mode, I see that it proceeds as expected until the `case $REPLY in` line, then suddenly stops without running through the case. I put an `exit 1` as a test after the last closing `fi` and can confirm the script simply jumps past `case` and stops, since there are no further instructions.

**What is going wrong in there, and why is it ditching the `case`?**

Documentation used to write this code:

- Flow control : http://linuxcommand.org/wss0120.php
- [Check if a directory exists in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script)
- Test building : http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS
- Test building using [[ ]] specific operators : [Bash regex =~ operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441521/bash-regex-operator)

**Run on *Debian*, with `bash` as terminal.**

Comment: ... Because the cases are supposed to be globs.

Comment: Paste your script in http://www.shellcheck.net/ to fix the syntax errors!

Comment: Look at the 2nd gray box of the first link you posted, about flow control. That example compares a variable with 1, 2, 3 (digits). Subsequent examples are even more complete, and they never use your intricated `[[ $REPLY ...]]`. You wrote your question really well, good job, but you should read the links you posted yourself!

Comment: Aside: The ABS is a very problematic resource (often outdated, showcasing bad practices in examples, etc). Consider http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/case and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression instead. The Wooledge wiki is also reliably well-maintained; see for instance [BashFAQ #31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) on `[[`.

Comment: Thanks for the advices. I put the code through shellcheck and also changed my `[[ $REPLY ...]])` to`Y|y)`. Working great now.

Comment: `http://linuxcommand.org/wss0120.php` is no longer available. Is there any mirror or copy for this page?

Comment: @Sabrina I don't know of any mirrors but the page is still available on archive.org (I tried the snapshot from the 8th of July 2017 which worked fine) : [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170708090643/http://linuxcommand.org/wss0120.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect:

```
" [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]] " )
```

Correct:

```
[Yy])
```

There are other errors in the OP code, but start with that...

Comment: In the glob `^` will match a literal `^`, not the beginning of line.  Try `Y|y)`

Comment: @WilliamPursell, Fixed & thanks for the needed recorrection.

Comment: As @WilliamPursell noted, `^` matched the literal ^ and my case was still overlooked. Changing to `Y|y)` and `*)` did work however. Thank you both !