# how to test if string does not exists in a file

Tags: perl, shell, unix

I'm searching a file which should not have this string "section" using shell/perl.

Please help me to find way `grep -vl` command returns a file names if strings exists.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749330/how-to-test-if-string-exists-in-file-with-bash-shell

Answer (score 5):

You may try like this:-

```
grep -Fxq "$MYFILENAME" file.txt
```

or may be like this:-

```
if grep -q SearchString "$File"; then
   Do Some Actions
fi
```

Comment: Did you just copy the answer from the duplicate and put it here?

Comment: The `if` statement would have been my answer too -- even before looking at the duplicate question. It's just the standard way. However, I'd add the `-F` and `-w` parameters to my `grep`. The `-F` turns off regular expressions, and the `-w` only selects against a fixed word.

Answer (score 4):

In **perl**:

```
    open(FILE,"<your file>");
    if (grep{/<your keyword>/} <FILE>){
       print "found\n";
    }else{
       print "word not found\n";
    }
    close FILE;
```

Answer (score -1):

A lot of times I'll do it this way:

```
for f in <your_files>; do grep -q "section" $f && echo $f || continue; done
```

That should print out a list of files that contain the word "section" in them.