# using grep as if condition inside awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I can use `grep -Fxq search-string text-file` outside of my awk, and it works they way I'd expect (found here [How to test if string exists in file with Bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749330/how-to-test-if-string-exists-in-file-with-bash-shell)). But, when I try to use that same grep command as an if statement inside awk, it seems to do nothing. Here's the basic usage I'm trying:

```
cat /var/log/somelogfile | awk '{ if (grep -Fxq $1 textfile) print "useful command $1" }'
```

Comment: `awk script` != `bash script` Why don't you explain what you're trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk's `system` function:

```
cat /var/log/somelogfile | awk '{ if (system("grep -Fxq " $1 " textfile")) print "useful command " $1; }'
```

See the [docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/awk.html).

Comment: You should not use `cat` with program that can read data itself, like `awk`, `sed`, `perl` etc.

Comment: Nor do you need grep when you are using awk.

Comment: It looks like the `grep` may be important to what the user is trying to do. I concede the `cat` point, though.

Comment: The grep was needed to check if a username (found in column 1 by awk) existed in the text file. I am parsing the cups page log to count the number of pages printed by each user and warn them if they exceed a certain limit. I wanted to run the script once a day, but not email the same user more than once a month, hence why I needed to check if they had already been warned ie if their username had already been added to the text file.

Comment: Grep is a system command, not an awk command. The stuff between the single quotes are bon a fied awk language, and grep is not part of that language. So you have to rely on the actual grep program and you call programs in awk with 'system()'. Again, see the docs.

Comment: Very useful answer. In my case, I had to do `if(system("grep " $1 " textfile > /dev/null") == "0") print ...`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for that, you can use anchors:

`awk '/^search-string$/ {do something}'`

Explanation:

1. `^` Beginning of the line
2. `$` End of line
3. `/^search-string$/` return true if matches just like `grep -Fxq`

`-x` for grep uses anchors. I believe `-F` is redundant.

Comment: That's testing for cases where a whole line matches a regexp which is completely different from testing for the existence of a string in a file as the OP is trying do do. The `-F` tells grep to look for strings instead of REs, in awk you use `index()` and `==` for that instead of `match()`, `//`, and `~`.

Answer (score 1):

It LOOKS like what you're trying to do is:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { strings[$0]; next }
{
    for (string in strings) {
        if ( index($0,string) ) {
            print "useful command", $1
            next
        }
    }
}
' textfile /var/log/somelogfile
```

We'll know for sure if/when you post some some sample input/output.

Answer (score 0):

If `grep` or `egrep` are insufficient for your text filtering, it might be easier to a perl one liner. `perl` offers useful [command line options](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html), like `-n -e` which will implicitly executes your arbitrary command inside `while` loop.

So for example:

```
  perl -ne 'if (/some line (.*)/) {print "useful command: $1\n"}' /var/log/somelogfile
```

will filter all the lines with "some line" text and will print everything after that text.

Comment: You should not use `cat` with program that can read data itself, like `awk`, `sed`, `perl` etc.

Comment: True, modified the command. Nevertheless, I commit this dreadful sin of `cat`ing files and then `grep`ping them since many years and I see it's drawbacks maybe once per year when I grep something *really* big. Otherwise you have nice data flow, with data source at left and filters one by one at right. Readability over performance.