# How to test if a string exists in a HTML file - Unix Script

Tags: string, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I am writing a ksh script. I have a pair of html files in a directory and I need to check whether or not the files contain one of two strings (the strings are mutually exclusive). I then rename the files based on which of the two strings they contain.

When testing I was able to use the following code on `.txt` files, but the functionality no longer works when testing for the strings in `.html` files:

```
outageString='Scheduled Outage List'
jobString='Scheduled Job List'

for file in `ls -1t $fileNameFormat | head -n 2`
do
    if grep -xq "$outageString" "$file"; then
        mv "$file" "$outageFileName"
    elif grep -xq "$jobString" "$file"; then
        mv "$file" "$jobFileName"
    fi
done
```

**Note:** I have tested the `ls` command above independently and it returns the appropriate files.

**File Content:**

```
<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
 <title>
 OUS: Scheduled Outage List
 </title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h3>
 OUS: Scheduled Outage List
 </h3>
 &nbsp; 
   .
   .
   .
```

**Q:** Does anyone have any insight as to why `grep` is not returning the appropriate value when searching for the strings in the two files(i.e., why `grep` does not recognize that the string exists in the file)?

Similar Question: [How to test if string exists in file with Bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749330/how-to-test-if-string-exists-in-file-with-bash-shell)

Comment: Need only the two most recent files added to the directory @AurélienLAJOIE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is in your use of:

```
grep -x
```

Since `grep` command with `-x` attempts to match exact full line. As per `man grep`:

```
-x, --line-regexp
    Only input lines selected against an entire fixed string or regular expression are 
    considered to be matching lines.
```

Just use `grep -Fq` instead of `grep -xq`.

**PS:** It is not recommended to use output from `ls` like this. Better use **globbing** directly in your `for` loop like this:

```
for file in *.html; do
    echo "processing $file"
done
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you for the quick response. I should have looked more closely into the flags I had selected.

Comment: The reason I chose to use `ls` in the `for` loop was because I needed to access only the two most recently added files in the directory.

Comment: Only problem with using `ls` like this is when filenames have whitespace, newline etc. That is just fyi

Comment: Yes, I have already run into this problem at a further point in the script and will attempt to use globbing directly to alleviate. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 2):

The -x option in grep matches an exact regexp match as a whole line, so because the line in the HTML document begins "OUS:" it won't match.

I can only guess that the .txt file didn't have this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  for file in $(grep -H "Scheduled Outage List" /path/to/files/*.html | cut -d: -f1);
do
        echo $file;
        # mv files around
 done
```