# Bash creating a string, if string already exists replace it

Tags: string, bash, sed

I would like to achieve this procedure.
I have this command:
`sed -i -e 's/few/asd/g' /usr/local/sbin/.myappenv`
This command works if in the file `.myappenv` there is a `few` string text. But this command fails to simply create the `asd` text wheter or not the `few` is found.

So, if there is the `few` text, **it should replace it**, if `few` text is missing, **just create it on the first line**.

***EDIT_:***

It should create the string on the first line of the document `.myappenv`, it should only be created if there is no coincidence.

The file `.myappenv` should contain =>

```
asd
```

If the file is already populated with `few` just replace it =>

```
asd
```

Comment: `just create it.` where? On the beginning of the line? On the end? At the 5th character?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Sorry for not specifying that, it should create it on the first line @KamilCuk

Comment: I edited the question to explain the problem I am facing @Cyrus

Comment: I still don't understand this. There seem to be two scenarios: the file contains `few`, or it does not. Can you show input and desired output for the two scenarios?

Comment: Hi @BenjaminW. the file is a set of env variables, the ``few`` could be found or not, if it is found I should replace it with ``asd`` if on that file, ``few`` is NOT found i just need to add ``asd`` sorry if the explanation is not clear. I am trying my best.

Comment: When the original file already has a line with `asd`, the requirements suggest that you want to add an additional line with `asd`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if there is the few text, it should replace it, if few text is missing, just create it on the first line.

That's an if.

```
if <file has text>; then <replace text>; else <add text to first line>; fi
```

or in bash:

```
file=/usr/local/sbin/.myappenv
if grep -q few "$file"; then
     sed 's/few/asd/' "$file"
else
     { 
        echo asd
        cat "$file"
     } > "$file".tmp
     mv "$file".tmp "$file"
fi
```

[How to test if string exists in file with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749330/how-to-test-if-string-exists-in-file-with-bash) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99350/how-to-insert-text-before-the-first-line-of-a-file and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals . You might interest yourself in some automation methods, like [ansible lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html) or [chezmoi](https://github.com/twpayne/chezmoi) depending on the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Using a single `awk` you can use this:

```sh
awk 'FNR == NR {if (/few/) {n = 1; nextfile}; next}
FNR == 1 && !n {print "asd"} n {gsub(/few/, "asd")} 1' file file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'H;$!d;x;/few/!s/^/asd/;t;s//asd/;s/.//' file
```

Make a copy of the file in the hold space (first line will have a prepended newline).

At the end of the file, if `few` is not matched, insert the literal `asd`.

Otherwise, replace the first occurrence of `few` with `asd` and remove the introduced newline at the start of the file.

To replace all occurrences of `few` with `asd` use:

```
sed 'H;$!d;x;/few/!s/^/asd/;t;s//asd/g;s/.//' file
```

---

Alternative:

```
grep -q few file && sed 's/few/asd/' file || (echo asd; cat file)
```