# Position of a string within a string using Linux shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

If I have the text in a shell variable, say `$a`:

```
a="The cat sat on the mat"
```

How can I search for "cat" and return 4 using a Linux shell script, or -1 if not found?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String contains in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash)

Comment: @Daniel This question asks for an index of substring too

Answer (score 82):

With bash

```
a="The cat sat on the mat"
b=cat
strindex() { 
  x="${1%%"$2"*}"
  [[ "$x" = "$1" ]] && echo -1 || echo "${#x}"
}
strindex "$a" "$b"   # prints 4
strindex "$a" foo    # prints -1
strindex "$a" "ca*"  # prints -1
```

Comment: +1 It also works in Dash, ash, ksh, pdksh, zsh. Dash and ash want `[ "$x" = "$1" ]` and pdksh wants `x=$2; x="${1%%$x*}"`, however.

Comment: @Zubair, bash 2.0 is 10 years old and 2 major releases behind (http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/). Can you update it?

Comment: This is just brilliant.  The first parameter substitution expression says "delete from the search expression on to the end", and the ${#x} is the length of what remains - which is the position of the search expression!

Comment: great answer, been using it for a while. just found out that a `*` in your search string will be interpreted as a wild card unless it is manually escape.  i added a copy of your answer with automatic escaping, but all credit to you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69960043/912236

Comment: @Orwellophile, to avoid pathname expansion of `$var` in `"${param%$var}"`, the easiest  is to quote it: `"${param%"$var"}"`. See [here](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2295).

Comment: Should `strindex()` return a zero (0) return code value, but print negative one (-1). No.

Answer (score 37):

You can use grep to get the byte-offset of the matching part of a string:

```
echo $str | grep -b -o str
```

As per your example:

```
[user@host ~]$ echo "The cat sat on the mat" | grep -b -o cat
4:cat
```

you can pipe that to awk if you just want the first part

```
echo $str | grep -b -o str | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"}{print $1}'
```

Comment: `cut -d: -f1` is a bit more lightweight than piping through awk

Comment: @Zubair: define "doesn't work"- the output is correct on my machine.

Comment: outputs '0:cat' on my mac

Comment: Gives '0:cat' on Mac and Ubuntu.

Comment: `colrm 2` could also replace the awk portion

Comment: If you go the `awk` route, please, use `awk -F:` to change the field separator. It is much easier and cleaner.

Comment: Note: You have to use `-abo` if greping a binary file.

Answer (score 10):

I used [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) for this

```
a="The cat sat on the mat"
test="cat"
awk -v a="$a" -v b="$test" 'BEGIN{print index(a,b)}'
```

Comment: awk gives +1 too great answer considering what the original poster requested. Howerer, there is a way to correct it: `awk -v a="$a" -v b="$test" 'BEGIN{print index(a,b)}' | xargs expr -1 +`

Answer (score 5):

```
echo $a | grep -bo cat | sed 's/:.*$//'
```

Comment: @Zubair - your command displays "4" on my Ubuntu 10.04 box. That's what I expect.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a version of the glenn jackman's answer with escaping, the complimentary reverse function `strrpos` and python-style `startswith` and `endswith` function based on the same principle.

Edit: updating escaping per @bruno's excellent suggestion.

```bash
strpos() { 
  haystack=$1
  needle=$2
  x="${haystack%%"$needle"*}"
  [[ "$x" = "$haystack" ]] && { echo -1; return 1; } || echo "${#x}"
}

strrpos() { 
  haystack=$1
  needle=$2
  x="${haystack%"$needle"*}"
  [[ "$x" = "$haystack" ]] && { echo -1; return 1 ;} || echo "${#x}"
}

startswith() { 
  haystack=$1
  needle=$2
  x="${haystack#"$needle"}"
  [[ "$x" = "$haystack" ]] && return 1 || return 0
}

endswith() { 
  haystack=$1
  needle=$2
  x="${haystack%"$needle"}"
  [[ "$x" = "$haystack" ]] && return 1 || return 0
}
```

Comment: pathname expansion is much more than `*` (`?` and `[..]`). The best way to prevent pathname expansion is to quote `$2` in `x=${haystack%%"$2"*}`

Comment: @Bruno "Today I Learned...."

Comment: @Orwellophile For `strpos()`, if the value of `$needle` is the empty string `''` (null) or some other un-matchable pattern, then the result stored in `$x` would be the value of `$haystack` itself. There can be no match, and so therefore nothing is deleted from an expanded `$haystack`. The variable expands normally by bash rules, and the value is stored in `$x`. Prevent empty arguments upon execution with the `someVariable="${1:?}"` format. It makes your functions MUCH more type safe, so to speak. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions

Comment: While having default values is normally a fantasic thing, I can't see how that would help in this case.  If `$needle` is empty, then `strpos` will echo position 0.  If `$needle` is not found, it will echo -1.  Errorlevels will be set to 0 and 1 respectively.  

That is entirely correct for `strpos`, conforms to JavaScript's behaviour, and seems logical to me.  It is also an essential component of https://gist.github.com/sfinktah/a432630706393d7bbe51f01508805cc6 (where I used these functions).

`strrpos` should return the length of the string if $needle is '', but defaults won't help there.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using `ripgrep` (aka `rg`).

```sh
❯ a="The cat sat on the mat"
❯ echo $a | rg --no-config --column 'cat'
1:5:The cat sat on the mat
❯ echo $a | rg --no-config --column 'cat' | cut -d: -f2
5
```

If you wanted to make it a function you can do:

```sh
function strindex() {
    local str=$1
    local substr=$2
    echo -n $str | rg --no-config --column $substr | cut -d: -f2
}
```

...and use it as such: `strindex <STRING> <SUBSTRING>`

```sh
strindex "The cat sat on the mat" "cat"
5
```

---

You can install `ripgrep` on MacOS with: `brew install --formula ripgrep`.

Answer (score 1):

A variation (bash) on @Orwellophile 's answer, done out the long way. However, it also does the comparison with string lengths instead of comparing strings. You never know how long a string might be! :-) Hopefully, while clearly longer, this answer will be clearer.

```
function strpos ()
{
    local -r needle="${1:?}"    ## Prevents empty strings
    local -r haystack="${2:?}"  ## Prevents empty strings

    ## From a copy, attempts to remove characters from the end of a string, greedily.
    local -r remainingHaystack="${haystack%%"$needle"*}"
    local -ir remainingHaystackLength="${#remainingHaystack}"

    ## When the needle is not found in haystack, these values will be equal.
    if (( $remainingHaystackLength == ${#haystack} )); then
        echo -n -1
        return 1
    fi
    
    echo -n $remainingHaystackLength
}
```

> If the pattern matches a **trailing portion** of the *expanded value of* **parameter**, then
> the result of the expansion is the value of parameter with the
> **shortest matching pattern** (the **‘%’** case) or the **longest matching
> pattern** (the **‘%%’** case) ***deleted***.

**Example:**

If parameter = "/usr/bin/foo/bin", and word = "/bin"

```
 ${parameter%word}    ## /usr/bin/foo/bin  --> /usr/bin/foo (non-greedy)
 ${parameter%%word}   ## /usr/bin/foo/bin  --> /usr         (greedy)
```

> If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in
> turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an
> array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, ***the pattern removal
> operation is applied to each member of the array*** in turn, and the
> expansion is the resultant list.

[Bash Reference Manual: Shell Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions)

Answer (score -1):

Most simple is -
**expr index "The cat sat on the mat" cat**

it will return 5

Comment: This solution does not meet the requirement of returning `-1` when the text value is not found. `expr` returns one (1) and prints zero (0) when a CHAR is not found, and so may cause ambiguity, depending on usage. Also if the `string='Cat in the Hat Strikes Back'` then `expr index "$string" 'Hat'` will print` 2`, because the form of the command is `index STRING CHARS` and not `index STRING String`. In this case it returns the position of the character `a`, because it is the second character in `$string`, meaning that `expr` uses **one (1) based indexing**, not **zero (0) based indexing**.