# Find position of a character in a file and store its position bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, position, character

I need to find all the positions of a specific character `##` in a file using Bash script and also store all positions for future use.

This is how the file looks like:

```
assert property ( ( req1 == 0 ) ##1 ( req1 == 1 ) ##1 !( req2 == 1 ) || (gnt1 == 0 ) );
assert property ( ( req1 == 0 ) ##1 !( req1 == 1 ) || ( gnt1 == 1 ) );
assert property ( ( req1 == 1 && req2 == 0 ) ##1 !( req2 == 1 ) || ( gnt1 == 0 ) );
```

In the above file I want to get all locations for this character (`##`) and store them as well. How can this be done using shell script?

Comment: What do you mean by "locations"? Maybe zero-indexed positions from the front of the lines?

Comment: What if three `#`s appear?

Comment: Or "locatoin" = 1 based from top of file thru the bottom? AND as we're about helping people **fix** their code, **what have you tried?** (update your Q, don't reply in comments please). Good luck.

Comment: By location I meant positions.

Comment: There will only be this character in the file ## not three #

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk for this:

```
awk -F'##' '
{
   for(i=1;i<NF;i++){
     printf "%d ",length($i)+offset+1
     offset+=length($i)+length(FS)
   }
   printf "\n"
   offset=0
}' file
```

The parameter delimiter `-F` is set as your pattern.

Loop through all portions of the line (`$1`,`$2`...) and print the length of each portion that actually indicates the position of the pattern (adding the `offset` for line that would contain more than one match).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

str1="assert property ( ( req1 == 0 ) ##1 ( req1 == 1 ) ##1 !( req2 == 1 ) || (gnt1 == 0 ) );"
str2="assert property ( ( req1 == 0 ) ##1 !( req1 == 1 ) || ( gnt1 == 1 ) );"
str3="assert property ( ( req1 == 1 && req2 == 0 ) ##1 !( req2 == 1 ) || ( gnt1 == 0 ) );"

char="##"

awk -v a="$str1" -v b="$char" 'BEGIN{print index(a,b)}' | xargs expr -1 +
awk -v a="$str2" -v b="$char" 'BEGIN{print index(a,b)}' | xargs expr -1 +
awk -v a="$str3" -v b="$char" 'BEGIN{print index(a,b)}' | xargs expr -1 +
```

The positions are 32, 32 and 45 for these examples. But there is only the first appearance of the ## char for each one. Not sure if you need to get more appearances.

Solution extracted from Dennis Williamsons comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031764/position-of-a-string-within-a-string-using-linux-shell-script)

Comment: Thank you, but I need to know the positions of all occurrences in the file for this character.