# How to find certain character position in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For a given string:

```
a="This is test.txt file"
```

How to find position of the `.` in a shell environment? It should return `13`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using BASH:

```
a="This is test.txt file"
s="${a%%.*}"            # remove all text after DOT and store in variable s
echo "$(( ${#s} + 1 ))" # get string length of $s + 1

13
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk -F. '{print length($1)+1}' <<< "$a"
13
```

Comment: Excellent. Can you give brief explanation of 2 line ( s="${a%%.*}" ) " ?

Comment: sure, I added some explanation in answer

Answer (score 1):

Clearly this is a duplicated question but all answers are not on both pages.

Additional useful information can be found at [Position of a string within a string using Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031764/position-of-a-string-within-a-string-using-linux-shell-script)

This script will find a single character or a multi-character string.
I've modified the code on the other page to fit the question here:

```
#strindex.sh
A="This is test.txt file"
B=.
strindex() {
X="${1%%$2*}"
[[ "$X" = "$1" ]] && echo -1 || echo "$[ ${#X} + 1 ]"
}
strindex "$A" "$B"
#end
```

This returns 13 as requested.

In the above example I would prefer to define the variables 'A' and 'B' with A="$(cat $1)" and B="$2" so the script can be used on any file and any search string from the command line.
Note I also changed the variables to upper case from the other page's example. This is not mandatory but some people think variables in upper case is a nice convention and easier to read and identify.