# Translate base64 encoder C source code to bash builtins script

Tags: c, bash, base64, built-in

Good day Stack you may think that this is the same question that has been answered before about the old `base64`, `xxd`, `hexdump` combination of commands to convert strings into base64, but instead of using external commands i'm trying to do the same only using builtins from bash like `printf`, `read`, `echo`... i am translating a C source from [here](http://fm4dd.com/programming/base64/base64_stringencode_c.htm) and i have the encoding working so far but i have stumbled into a problematic C line

```
char b64[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
...
char *p;
...
p = strchr(b64, c);
...
in[phase] = p - b64; //Problematic line
```

The thing is that `p` and `b64` are char arrays and i don't understand what's doing the arithmetic expression with the two char arrays to obtain a number, it could be something like not or xor O_o. I'm still learning C and i don't know a lot.

This is what i have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -r b64=( {A..Z} {a..z} {0..9} {+,/} )

function ord() {
    for i in {0..3}; do
        printf '%d ' "'${1:$i:1}"
    done
}

#TODO
function decodeblock() {
    local out in=( $(ord $1) )
    out[0]=$(( ${in[0]} << 2 | ${in[1]} >> 4 ))
    out[1]=$(( ${in[1]} << 4 | ${in[2]} >> 2 ))
    out[2]=$(( ${in[2]} << 6 | ${in[3]} >> 0 ))
    printf "%s" "${out[@]}"
}

function encodeblock() {
    local in=( $(ord "$1") ) len=$2 out index
    index=$(( ${in[0]} >> 2 ))
    out[0]=${b64[$index]}
    index=$(( ((${in[0]} & 0x03) << 4) | ((${in[1]} & 0xf0) >> 4) ))
    out[1]=${b64[$index]}
    index=$(( ((${in[1]} & 0x0f) << 2) | ((${in[2]} & 0xc0) >> 6) ))
    out[2]=$( (($len > 1)) && echo -n ${b64[$index]} || echo -n '=' )
    index=$(( ${in[2]} & 0x3f ))
    out[3]=$( (($len > 2)) && echo -n ${b64[$index]} || echo -n '=' )
    printf "%s" "${out[@]}"
}

function b64_decode() {
    local c i=0 phase=0 block p b64src="$1"
    for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#b64src} ; i++)); do
        c="${b64src:$i:1}"
        [[ "$c" == '=' ]] && decodeblock "$b64src" && break
        p="$c${b64[@]##*$c}"
        if [[ -n "$p" ]]; then
            #TODO
            b64src[$phase]=
            phase=$(( ($phase + 1) % 4 ))
            if [[ $phase -eq 0 ]]; then
                decodeblock "$b64src"
                b64src=''
            fi
            ((i++))
        fi
    done
}

function b64_encode() {
    local block j=0 len clrstr="$1"
    while [[ -n "${clrstr:$j:1}" ]]; do
        len=0
        for (( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )); do
            block+="${clrstr:$j:1}"
            [[ -n "${clrstr:$j:1}" ]] && { ((len++)) ; ((j++)); }
        done
        [[ -n $len ]] && encodeblock "${block[@]}" $len
        block='' ; len=0
    done
}

echo -n 'hello world' | base64 #DEBUG
b64_encode 'hello world' #DEBUG

b64_decode "$( b64_encode 'hello world' )"
```

Regards and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strchr(b64, c)` searches the character `c` into the string `b64` and returns a pointer to it if found; subtracting `b64` from this value simply yields the index of the character inside `b64`.

Long story short it's getting the index of `c` in `b64`. As for how to implement this in the shell, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031764/position-of-a-string-within-a-string-using-linux-shell-script) you may find some inspiration.

Comment: This is why C is so hard and fun, simple things like this looks complex.