# in bash, how to dynamicaly create a file name k with content v based on the k="v" written in a file?

Tags: bash

we have an arbitrary number of files that I know they have this format

```
k="v"
```

and I know that k does not contain and = sign. I want to treat k as a delimiter.

example1.txt

```
b="a=c ==\n=/n/ //a=\n:=dd"
```

example2.txt:

```
e="====a\\nn/ //a=\n:=dd"
```

example3.txt

```
My-key="my-value"
```

etc!

I want to iterate over the files and do these:

- get the key (everything before the first = sign)
- get the value (everything after the first = sign not including the double quotes before and after
- create a file named the key from the first step and populate the file with the value from the second step above

in the example above the output is gonna be:

b.txt

```
a=c ==\n=/n/ //a=\n:=dd
```

e.txt

```
====a\\nn/ //a=\n:=dd
```

My-key.txt

```
my-value
```

In summary, I want to dissect the content of the $filename into k and v according to the first = sign as a delimiter and then create a file named k containing the value v

How to do this

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT_DIR="/input"
OUTPUT_DIR="/output"


for filename in "$INPUT_DIR"/*; do
    echo "$filename"
    . "$filename"
    # as a result of the last line a k and v is put into the env
    # I want a file named k and the value be the same as the $k
    # so that I can read the same env var (a secret) from both env and from the file
    # one way of getting the KEY
    # KEY=$(cat "$filename" | cut -d '=' -f 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
    # how to get the VALUE? without ""
    # how to write $VALUE to the file named $KEY

done
```

Comment: You have a clear picture of what you want to do and a basic starting script, so where exactly are you stuck? Each step of this seems easily searchable online.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427262/how-to-read-a-file-into-a-variable-in-shell to read the contents of the file, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031764/position-of-a-string-within-a-string-using-linux-shell-script to parse the contents, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162406/open-and-write-data-to-text-file-using-bash to output the contents to a file. These should get you 80%+ of the way there.

Comment: how to handle edge cases such as \n

Comment: I got stock in this step

Comment: the filename is dynamic!

Comment: looks like someone provided a template and you're supposed to replace `# your code here` with your coding attempt soooo ... what code have you tried and how did it fail? *`I got stuck`* doesn't really tell us much other than you haven't done anything (yet) ... ?

Comment: no. I added that for clarity

Comment: it is an mvce. the context is puling secret from hashicorp vault and sharing with an agent init container

Comment: can the input files contain more than one line? are *all* lines of the format `k="v"` or are there going to be some lines we need to ignore? if we do need to ignore some lines then please update the sample inputs to show a few such lines; across all the input files could there be more than one line for `k` and if so are we supposed to write all `v` (values) to new file `k` or just the 'last' `v` (value)?

Comment: only one k,v  pair and one line

Comment: I added the answer from chatgpt

Comment: if chatgpt gave you an answer that works ... what's the question?

Comment: I later asked it. I tested for one example. I need to know why it is doing sed 's/"//g')

Comment: I haven't tried running the chatgpt script but a simple test ... run the script as is and display the contents of the resulting files; then remove `sed 's/"//g"`, run the script again and dispay the contents of the resulting files; compare the two sets of file contents ... what's the difference?

Comment: [ChatGPT solutions are banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)

Comment: did not know that. going to edit it

Comment: Like most ChatGPT answers, this one is wrong. I assume `sed` was *intended* to remove quotes from something like `foo="bar"`, but it would also incorrectly remove quotes from something like `foo='"bar"`, where the quotes were literal, not part of the shell syntax.

Comment: It would work for *some* inputs, but ChatGPT isn't actually reasoning about how the shell works; it's just regurgitating text based on shell code (of unknown correctness or applicability to your problem) that it was trained on.

Comment: I know that I am gonna have "" for v. I know that my format is gonna be k="v"

Comment: I added a piece of my own code

Comment: What about `k="\"foo\""`? If you know that the *only* quotes are going to be surrounding the value, then there are simpler answers than what ChatGPT proposed. If not, then ChatGPT's answer is incorrect. ChatGPT neither produces good, general code, nor explains *why* it produces whatever it does.

Comment: I edited and clarified the purpose of this

Comment: What's the *purpose* of these files? Do you really just need whatever literal shell code that might follow the `=`, or do you need the the actual *value* that would be assigned to the variable if the assignment were executed by the shell? There's all sorts of stuff that could be on the RHS that would not simply be assigned literally to the name on the left.

Comment: I.e., if you are later going to do something like `read foo < k`, the value of `foo` may be *wildly* different from what `k` would have been assigned originally.

Comment: I think I need to write a new question . this became too complicated. The purpose is that if source the file, the same value I get from the env I can read from the file

Comment: your question mentions nothing about needing to `source` a file and/or dealing with 'env'ironment values; your latest comment basically invalidates the entire question and all of the answers you've received so far

Comment: I added a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78071318/in-bash-how-to-dynamically-write-use-k-and-v-from-variable-k-and-v

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT_DIR="input"
OUTPUT_DIR="output"

for filename  in "$INPUT_DIR"/*; do
    echo "Content of $filename:"
    file_content=$(<"$filename")
    echo "$file_content"
    key=$(echo "$file_content" | awk -F'="|"' '{print $1}')
    echo key: $key
    value=$(echo "$file_content" | awk -F'="|"' '{print $2}')
    echo value: $value
    printf "%s" "$value" > $OUTPUT_DIR/$key.txt
done
```

Output:

```
Content of input/example1.txt:
b="a=c ==\n=/n/ //a=\n:=dd"
key: b
value: a=c ==\n=/n/ //a=\n:=dd
Content of input/example2.txt:
e="====a\\nn/ //a=\n:=dd"
key: e
value: ====a\\nn/ //a=\n:=dd
Content of input/example3.txt:
My-key="my-value"
key: My-key
value: my-value
```

Output files content

```
cd output/
$ cat My-key.txt 
my-value
$ cat e.txt 
====a\\nn/ //a=\n:=dd
$ cat b.txt 
a=c ==\n=/n/ //a=\n:=dd
```

Comment: What about `k="\"foo\""`?

Comment: `k="\"foo\""` is not in question scope. I'm trying to help

Comment: Based on the question, that's no less likely than `k="x"`. OP has provided no context that would allow us to guess what might be inside the double quotes.

Comment: I edited and clarified the purpose of this

Comment: @chepner OP also didn't say it would include the value you provided. My answer solves the problem described in the question at the time I wrote it - I'm not saying that the solution works for every edge case pattern not described in the question. Let's let OP choose whether the answer meets expectations

Comment: I added a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78071318/in-bash-how-to-dynamically-write-use-k-and-v-from-variable-k-and-v

Answer (score 0):

The key here is the `IFS` bash variable: It sets the field separator which defaults to one or more whitespaces. If we set this to the equal sign, we can easily parse the contents of the file:

```bash
#set -x
INPUT_DIR=./input
OUTPUT_DIR=./output

for filename in $INPUT_DIR/*
do
    IFS='=' read out_filename contents < $filename
    echo $contents > $OUTPUT_DIR/$out_filename
done
```

Notes

- The `IFS='='` part tells the `read` command to use the equal sign to separate the fields.
- The `read` command reads 2 fields from a file: the `out_filename` and `contents`
- Uncomment the `set -x` line if you want to see all script's steps to print out, useful for debugging

## Update

Thank you for the inputs from @Barmar and @chepner. I have revised my solution, which use `sed` to remove the quotes:

```bash
# set -x
INPUT_DIR=./input
OUTPUT_DIR=./output

for filename in $INPUT_DIR/*
do
    IFS='=' read out_filename contents < $filename
    sed 's/"//g' <<< $contents > $OUTPUT_DIR/$out_filename
done
```

Comment: Remember to quote variables.

Comment: OP asked why `sed` was needed, and you instead provided an answer with the exact error that `sed` was used to avoid (namely, the assignment statement might include quotes which should not be considered part of the variable's value).

Comment: For `k="v"`, this will set `contents` to the string `"v"`, not the string `v`.

Comment: `sed 's/"//g'` will also remove any embedded double quotes

Comment: That removes too many quotes, which is why I ranted against ChatGPT in the comments.

Comment: I added a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78071318/in-bash-how-to-dynamically-write-use-k-and-v-from-variable-k-and-v