# How to dynamically write use k and v from variable k and v?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

we have an arbitrary number of files that I know they have this format

```
export k="v"
```

and I know that k does not contain and = sign. I want to treat k as a delimiter.

0.txt

```
export a="x=y ==\n=/n/ //a=\n:=dd"
```

1.txt

```
export b="====x\\nn/ //y=\n:=dd"
```

2.txt

```
export My_key="my-value"
```

etc!

I want to iterate over the files and do these:

- source the file
- get the key (everything before the first = sign)
- get the value
- create a file named the key from the first step and populate the file with the value from the second step above - The source of truth for the value is the value coming from the env as a result of running the source command

bash.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT_DIR="input"
OUTPUT_DIR="output"

for filename in "$INPUT_DIR"/*; do
    source "$filename"
    # the three lines below is something I tried and it did not work
    # key=$(cat "$filename" | cut -d '=' -f 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
    # VALUE=$(eval echo "\$$key")
    # printf "%s" "$VALUE" > "$OUTPUT_DIR/$key"
done

python3 test.py
```

test.py

```
import os

a_env, a_file =  os.environ["a"], open("output" + "/" + "a", "r").read()
b_env, b_file =  os.environ["b"], open("output" + "/" + "b", "r").read()
Mykey_env, Mykey_file =  os.environ["My_key"], open("output" + "/" + "My_key", "r").read()

assert a_env == a_file
assert b_env == b_file
assert Mykey_env == Mykey_file
```

How can I make it work? The context is that some sidecar container is injecting secrets into files named 0, 1, 2, 3, etc in the input directory with the format of `export k="v"` - I want those to be available both as an env variable and file and I want the file name to be the key

remember that the source of truth for the value is from env after running the source

Comment: Duplicate (?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78070483/in-bash-how-to-dynamicaly-create-a-file-name-k-with-content-v-based-on-the-k-v#78070483

Comment: No it is different. I added export and added python test

Comment: Can you explain what are you really trying to do, the big picture behind? Not just your idea to implement a solution. Explain the goal

Comment: hashicorp vault agent injector pulls secrets into a sidecar container. the content is `export k="v"` - in docker-entrypoint, for each file, I want to source the file and also create another file based on the input file.

Comment: but these the details not needed. it just makes the question confusing. I just need to know how to do what I explained in my question

Comment: and forgot to say, the reason I want secret values to be stored in file is that some secrets are needed as file such as cert files. but it is not in the scope of the questino as mentioned before

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code (particularly the fact that `value` is set but `VALUE` is used).  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: The code that you tried works if you replace `$VALUE` with `$value`.  You could simplify the setting of `value` by using `value=${!key}`.

Comment: Note that ALL_UPPERCASE variable names (like `INPUT_DIR` and `VALUE`) are best avoided because there is a danger of clashes with the large number of special ALL_UPPERCASE variables that are used in shell programming.  See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375).

Comment: @pjh why I am not able to do the same in sh? I would rather write sh and not bash script

Comment: @AminBa, Bash can do many things that `sh` can not do.  If you are not  interested in Bash solutions then please remove the `bash` tag from the question.  It's causing people to waste their time.

Comment: *Why* do you need them as files? The point of the `export` statements is to create environment variables that allow arbitrary code to access the values. You should just execute the code that would read the files in a shell that has already sourced the original files. E.g., `(. 0.txt; python code_that_needs_a_var.py;)`

Comment: The reason why the value agent produces those shell statements is so that you can immediately use `eval` to put them into *your* environment, without committing them to disk. Your sidecar container is creating a security vulnerability. The container that needs the secret(s) should be interfacing with Vault directly.

Answer (score 0):

this worked. I dont know if there is any problem with this approach or not

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT_DIR="input"
OUTPUT_DIR="output"

# Iterate over each file in the input directory
for filename in "$INPUT_DIR"/*; do
    source "$filename"
    key=$(cat "$filename" | cut -d '=' -f 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
    eval echo -n "\$$key" > "$OUTPUT_DIR/$key"
done

python3 test.py
```

Comment: Why `eval` ?? Not needed AFAIK.

Comment: because I dont want to do text operations after sourcing (exporting) - that is how I ensure the source truth for the value is what we have in env not in the file

Comment: That you're using `eval` is itself a problem. It's a huge security problem. And what is the `python3 test.py` doing in that script? Also, given your problem statement it shouldn't be necessary to `source` the file. As chepner pointed out you shouldn't do any of this because you're introducing potential security bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you don't know in advance what variable the `source` command will modify. It could be anything, including a variable named `key` or `OUTPUT_DIR`.

The following takes care of this, does not use `eval` (not safe) and does not use uppercase user variable names (discouraged practice with bash), but it assumes that your bash is less than 15 years old (if you are under macOS you can install a recent bash version with MacPorts or Homebrew).

You can use `mapfile`, `=~` and `BASH_REMATCH` to test the input format and extract the name of the key. A simple indirection (`${!key}`) gives you the value:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

declare input_dir="input"
declare output_dir="output"

mkdir -p "$output_dir"
shopt -s nullglob

for filename in "$input_dir"/*; do
  mapfile -t < "$filename"
  if ! [[ "${MAPFILE[0]}" =~ ^export[[:space:]]+([^=]+)\=.*$ ]] ||
     (( ${#MAPFILE[@]} != 1 )); then
    printf '%s: invalid file format\n' "$filename"
    continue
  fi
  key="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  odir="$output_dir"
  case "$key" in
    key)
      source "$filename"
      printf '%s\n' "$key" > "$output_dir/key"
      ;;
    output_dir)
      source "$filename"
      printf '%s\n' "$output_dir" > "$odir/$key"
      output_dir="$odir"
      ;;
    *) 
      source "$filename"
      printf '%s\n' "${!key}" > "$output_dir/$key"
      ;;
  esac
done

python3 test.py
```

Notes:

- We `set -eu` to exit on errors or expansion of undefined variables.
- We create the output directory, in case it does not exist yet
- We enable the `nullglob` option to expand `"$input_dir"/*` as an empty string, instead of the default literal `"$input_dir"/*`, if there are no input files.
- We test the input file format before sourcing it (one line only that matches `export key=val`). It is not absolutely safe because one single line with this format could be anything like `export key=$(rm -rf ~)`, but it is probably a bit safer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you obviously don't care about code injection, one simple approach would be to - either before or after sourcing the file - extract everything before the first equal sign.

I assume that, as in the examples you posted, the export statement starts in the **first** column of the **first** line of the txt file:

```
left_part=$(head -n 1.txt | cut -d = -f 1 <1.txt | tr -s ' ')
```

This stores something like `export b` on `left_part`.

The purpose of the `head` is to catch a case like this:

```
export x="ab c
 ddef"
```

The purpose of the `tr` is to catch a case like this:

```
export            y=z
```

Now you just have to remove everything up to the space:

```
varname=${left_part#* }
```

Note that this does **not** catch the following case:

```
export \
 b=c
```

If you want to catch all bborder cases, you would have to define exactly the syntax for the txt files you are going to source.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct question first: you have shell code that needs to be executed, and that's what `eval` is for. This code makes the following assumptions:

1. Each `txt` file contains nothing *except* `export` statements.
2. Each `export` command is on *one* line (no line continuations present)
3. Each `export` command performs exactly *one* assignment.

---

```
for f in *.txt; do
    while IFS='=' read k v; do
        # Don't bother storing a trailing newline,
        # since the entire contents of the file
        # are intended to represent a single file.
        printf '%s' "$(eval "$v")" > "$k"
    done
done
```

---

However, there's already a program that relaxes all three of the assumptions I made above, and has been well tested: the shell! What you *appear* to want is for some arbitrary code to have access to the variables that the text files would provide, if they were sourced. Well, then, just source them!

```
(. 0.txt 1.txt 2.txt; python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["a"], os.environ["b"], os.environ["My-key"])')
```