# How to search for specific characters within a string?

Tags: shell, unix

String :

```
 name@gmail.com
```

Want to check for :

```
@
.com
```

if those two are found, I want to set my boolean true

```
bool_one=true
```

How do I do this? I tried

```
if [ $word|grep[@] = $word]
```

but it's not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String contains in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
s='name@gmail.com'

[[ "$s" == *@*.com ]] && echo "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also

```
s='name@gmail.com'

[[ "$s" =~ (.*)@(.*)\.com ]] && echo "name: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} domain ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.com"
```