# How can I search a group of files for any part of a string?

Tags: bash, search, awk, find

All I want to do is to search a directory of files for ANY part of a string. Here is the section of my code that processes this:

```
(input is set through user input)

input2=$(eval find . -name "$input" -print | sed -n 1p) #Using find to search for the file I need to read

... (Checking the file I 'found' actually exists)

out=$(eval $(shuf -n 1 "$input2")) #Shuffle it randomly

echo "$out" #Echo the output
```

If I had the file 'date' with the contents `date "+%A %d %B %Y"` I could type 'date' and get the intended result but 'What is the date' would fail with

```
find: paths must precede expression: is 
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

What is the easiest way to fix this problem?

#### edit

I haven't tried much as I am at a loss of what to do. I have tried wildcards in the search string but they don't work at all. Here is the entire input-to-output part of the source code:

```
while true; do

  echo -n ">"
  read input
  input=${input,,}

  echo "[DEBUG]: Recieved $input"

  echo "[IO]: Accessing database"

  input2=$(eval find . -name "$input" -print | sed -n 1p) || out="WARNING: Input/Output Error{TYPE=IO.GENERAL, VALUE=$input2}"

  echo "[INPUT2]: Recieved $input2"

  if [ ! -f "$input2" ]
  then
    input2="./db/unknowncommand"
  fi

  #out=$(<"db/$input") || out="WARNING: Input/Output ERROR" #Old 'just print whatever is in the file approach

  out=$(eval $(shuf -n 1 "$input2")) || out="WARNING: Input/Output ERROR{TYPE=IO.GENERAL, VALUE=$input}" #Random output

  echo "$out"
  ./JAISpeak "$out" #A small text-to-speech program I made

done
```

Comment: Are you trying to search _filenames_ for an input string, or search through the files themselves?

Comment: please, show your REAL work = what you really tried. The above is only holy praying what you want be done...

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash) relevant?

Comment: @TravisJacobs Yes, that's the idea, I just need to read the filename and see if my string is contained in it.

Comment: @JeffBowman I'm trying to search the **filenames**, _not the contents of the files_, to clarify.

Comment: @JackMawer could you `ls` the files in your dir, then `grep` for the desired string? Wildcards would work with `grep`.

Comment: If i understand : you want the input "what is the date" to look for filenames that contain either "what" or "is" or "the" or "date" ?

Comment: have you tried `grep date *`?

Comment: @OlivierDulac that is the general idea. The point is that I will _never_ have a file in my 'database' named 'what', 'is' or 'the' so only date would match, but doing it this way would mean I could say anything with the word 'date' in it and probably get the intended answer to my question.

Comment: I see the problem : the eval will evaluate "$input2", and find will have then to "find . -name what is the name ....", so it sees "is" as something that ought to be a path as it doesn't recognise a command there. You need to drop the eval, first. but also you need to loop over $input2 if you want to look for each words separately

Comment: @dtmilano This wouldn't solve the problem, because my file is called 'date' and I am trying to find the word date in the string 'What is the date?' (for example). In short,
`date` **=** `what is the date?`

Comment: and "${input,,}" looks wrong... on my (old) bash it doesn't parse, and is an error. Do you mean : `input2="${input}"` ? (why the 2 commas?)

Comment: @OlivierDulac The find without the eval seemed to turn up a blank string every time, and sometimes an error saying find doesn't exist. On a whim, I added eval and it worked fine.

Comment: @OlivierDulac the $(input,,) is a bash 4.0 thingy that converts the string to lowercase so it matches any case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the "look for any part of the string in filenames" part, I'd do:

```
input2=$(for partname in ${input}; do find . -name "${partname}" -print ; done)
```

This will match every occurrence it can...
If you only need the first occurrence (weird, but hey, it's a bit the same with $PATH) :

```
input2=$(for partname in ${input}; do find . -name "${partname}" -print ; done | head -1)
```

Note that i use `${input}` instead of `"${input}"` on purpose: I want to separate each words in ${input} and loop over each one individually.

I let you revise the rest of your program ^^ (I need to go ...)

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks very much for helping me!

Comment: Well, since I deleted the rest of my program in a hard drive format, thanks for giving me a place to restart from. Might switch to a universal programming language now.