# Get files in bash script that contain an underscore

Tags: linux, bash, debian

In a directory with a bunch of files that look like this:

```
./test1_November 08, 2014 AM.flv
./test2.flv
./script1.sh
./script2.sh
```

I want to process only files that have an .flv extension and no underscore. I'm trying to eliminate the files with underscores without much luck.

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=$(find . -mtime 0) 
for f in "${FILES}"
do
        if [[ "$f" != *_* ]]; then
                echo "$f"
        fi
done
```

This gives me no files. Changing the `!=` to `==` gives me all files instead of just those with an underscore. [Other answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash) indicate this should work.

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Don't parse the output of `find`! that's what you're missing... Use globs (as shown in anubhava's answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this extended glob pattern:

```
shopt -s extglob
echo +([^_]).flv
```

`+([^_])` will match 1 or more of any non underscore character.

**Testing:**

```
ls -l *flv
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 staff 0 Nov  8 12:44 test1_November 08, 2014 AM.flv
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 staff 0 Nov  8 12:44 test2.flv

echo +([^_]).flv
test2.flv
```

To process these files in a loop use:

```
for f in +([^_]).flv; do
   echo "Processing: $f"
done
```

PS: Not sure you're using `-mtime 0` in your `find` as my answer is for the requiremnt:

> **I want to process only files that have an .flv extension and no underscore**

Comment: Definitely the best approach. You should explicit how to do a loop on these files.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked the `-mtime 0` in OP... that would be more difficult to achieve with globs...

Comment: Actually I am not sure why OP is using `-mtime 0` because OP wrote requirement as: **I want to process only files that have an .flv extension and no underscore**

Comment: I'm confused too about OP.

Comment: The mtime was to get files modified in the last 24 hours

Comment: This works very well and is short and to-the-point as well. If I still need to work with the file mtime I can do so inside the loop but as per my request, this is awesome.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass multiple patterns to `find` and include a not

```
find . -name "*.flv" -not -name "*_*"
```

You can loop over the results of `find` by piping it into a `while`

```
find -name "*.flv" -not -name "*_*" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
    echo "$filename"
done
```

or you can forgo the loop completely and use `xargs`

```
find -name "*.flv" -not -name "*_*" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 echo
```

Comment: Good answer. You should show the OP how to perform a loop on the result of `find` (with `-print0` and the appropriate `read`), with the caveat that `-print0` is not POSIX.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I like the way you think, but I'm not entirely sure what the OP wants to do. I have found that a lot of people who want to loop can actually get away with `xargs` instead

Comment: Then show both options `;)` or ask OP to clarify what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf not sure if I missed something there :D

Comment: No problem, I fixed that for you.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I've been schooled :)

Comment: I don't really need a loop, just need to process each file in a result set.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
for f in "${FILES}"
```

The quotes are preventing word splitting, so entire list of filenames is being processed as a single item. What you want is:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for f in $FILES
```

The `IFS` setting makes it use newlines as the word delimiters, so you can have filenames with spaces in them.

A better way to write loops like this is to avoid using the variable:

```
find ... | while read -r f
do
    ...
done
```

Comment: And you're subject to pathname expansion if filenames contain wildcards or square brackets. So you should also add the `set -f` somewhere... that's becoming a bit clunky.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I've added a `find | while read` loop to show how to do this without requiring any word splitting.