# How to print entire line in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, awk

I'm new to bash scripting and I've been trying to print out the entire line but couldn't find a way to work.

This is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
MOTD=`cat /etc/motd | awk '{print $1}'`
if [ "$MOTD" = "WARNING" ]
then
    echo "Audit Criteria: Warning banner exist."
    echo "Vulnerability: No."
    echo "Details: $MOTD "
else
    echo "Audit Criteria: Warning banners does not exist."
    echo "Vulnerability: Yes."
    echo "Details: $MOTD "
fi
```

my output is:

```
Audit Criteria: Warning banner exist.
Vulnerability: No.
Details: WARNING:
```

instead of the `WARNING:Authorized uses only
All activity may be monitored and reported.` , only "WARNING" appeared in the Details:

I believe the problem lies on the

```
MOTD=`cat /etc/motd | awk '{print $1}'`
```

and

`if [ "$MOTD" = "WARNING" ]`  parts, I've tried `{print$0}` but still could not get it to work.

Comment: This is expected, as you are assigning only the first word of the message to the variable `MOTD`.

Comment: Some minor problems.  You should not use `cat` with programs that can read data itself, like `awk`.  You should avoid old and outdated back-tics, use parentheses.  So change the  `MOTS` line to: `MOTD=$(awk '{print $1}' /etc/motd)`

Comment: @Skynet please take care when editing after a previous edit has already been submitted. Your edit undid a lot of improvements that I made to the question.

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't checked that another edit was undergoing @TomFenech

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to get the first line of `/etc/motd`, not the first word. If so, use the following:

```
MOTD=$(head -1 /etc/motd)
```

and then do the string comparison with

```
if [[ $MOTD == WARNING* ]; then
```

You can check [String contains in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229551/1983854) for more information about check if a string contains a specific substring in bash.

Comment: Or `MOTD=$(awk 'NR==1' /etc/motd)`

Comment: And then the test would be `[[ $MOTD == WARNING* ]]`

Comment: @Jotne, for efficiency, you'd want `awk 'NR==1 {print; exit}'`

Comment: That's it, @glennjackman ! Thanks, I was testing it, you were quite faster :)

Comment: Just wanted to add the reason that OPs command doesn't work is they were just printing the first field with `$1`

Comment: @glennjackman or just `awk '{print;exit}'` or `awk '1;{exit}'`

Comment: thanks a lot!! didnt expect you guys to reply so fast.. the output worked. once again thanks!!

Comment: `IFS= read -r MOTD < /etc/motd` would be the most efficient way to get the first line.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it would be simpler to do the whole thing in awk:

```
awk 'NR==1{
    if($1=="WARNING") {
        print "Audit Criteria: Warning banner exists."
        print "Vulnerability: No."
    }
    else { 
        print "Audit Criteria: Warning banner does not exist."
        print "Vulnerability: Yes."
    }
    print "Details: " $0
    exit
}' /etc/motd
```

The condition `NR==1` and the `exit` at the end of the block mean that only the first line of the file is processed.

The code above is the most similar to your bash script but you could make it a lot shorter using variables:

```
awk 'NR==1{if($1=="WARNING"){b="exists";v="No"}else{b="does not exist";v="Yes"}
printf "Audit Criteria: Warning banner %s.\nVulnerability: %s.\nDetails: %s\n",b,v,$0
exit}' /etc/motd
```

Comment: note `/etc/motd` normally contains a lot of lines. Hence, you may want to end everything with a `exit` to avoid a lot of output.

Comment: @fedorqui I wasn't aware of that, thanks for letting me know. I've edited to only process the first line, then exit.

Comment: Yes, motd stands for `m`essge `o`f `t`he `d`ay and is used to show many things (or none). It is commonly linked to `/etc/issue` and can contain security informations, the name of the server...

Comment: Thanks for the info. I thought it meant [Match of the Day](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b007t9y1) ;) By the way, information is uncountable (we don't say "informations") :)

Comment: Ooops yet another synonym for motd: my Mistake Of The Day! Or even Misspelling of the day :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using only using variable MOTD and it is having only value WARNING.

```
#!/bin/bash

MOTD=`cat /etc/motd | awk '{print $1}'`    
if [ "$MOTD" = "WARNING" ]    
then
    echo "Audit Criteria: Warning banner exist."        
    echo "Vulnerability: No."       
    echo "Details: `cat /etc/motd` "    
else        
    echo "Audit Criteria: Warning banners does not exist."      
    echo "Vulnerability: Yes."      
    echo "Details: `cat /etc/motd`"    
fi
```

Or in case if you have multiple lines in /etc/motd and you need to print only one line then.

```
#!/bin/bash

MOTDL=`grep WARNING /etc/motd`
MOTD=`cat /etc/motd | awk '{print $1}'`    
if [ "$MOTD" = "WARNING" ]    
then
    echo "Audit Criteria: Warning banner exist."        
    echo "Vulnerability: No."       
    echo "Details: $MOTDL "    
else        
    echo "Audit Criteria: Warning banners does not exist."      
    echo "Vulnerability: Yes."      
    echo "Details: $MOTDL"    
fi
```