# How to test for a character (or string) in a filename in dash

Tags: shell, dash-shell

I have a string (a filename, actually) that I want to test whether they contain a character:

```
NEEDLE="-"
for file in mydirectory/*
do
   if [NEEDLE IS FOUND IN STRING]
   then
       # do something
   else
       # do something else
   fi
done
```

Basically this is the same question as [String contains in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash), except for dash instead of bash (ideally shell-neutral, which is usually the case with dash-code anyway)

The [[ operator does not exist in dash, therefore the answer to that question does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a `case` statement, no need to spawn an external program:

```
NEEDLE="-"
for file in mydirectory/*; do
    case "$file" in
        *"$NEEDLE"*) echo "do something" ;;
        *) echo "do something else" ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `grep -q` inside `for loop`:

```
NEEDLE="-"
for file in mydirectory/*; do
    if grep -q "$NEEDLE" "$file"; then
       echo "do something"
    else
       echo "do something else"
    fi
done
```